# Why is numpy's einsum slower than numpy's built-in functions?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, linear-algebra

I've usually gotten good performance out of numpy's einsum function (and I like it's syntax). @Ophion's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365073/why-is-numpys-einsum-faster-than-numpys-built-in-functions) shows that - for the cases tested - einsum consistently outperforms the "built-in" functions (sometimes by a little, sometimes by a lot). But I just encountered a case where einsum is much slower. Consider the following equivalent functions:

```
(M, K) = (1000000, 20)
C = np.random.rand(K, K)
X = np.random.rand(M, K)

def func_dot(C, X):
    Y = X.dot(C)
    return np.sum(Y * X, axis=1)

def func_einsum(C, X):
    return np.einsum('ik,km,im->i', X, C, X)

def func_einsum2(C, X):
    # Like func_einsum but break it into two steps.
    A = np.einsum('ik,km', X, C)
    return np.einsum('ik,ik->i', A, X)
```

I expected `func_einsum` to run fastest but that is not what I encounter. Running on a quad-core cpu with hyperthreading, numpy version 1.9.0.dev-7ae0206, and multithreading with OpenBLAS, I get the following results:

```
In [2]: %time y1 = func_dot(C, X)
CPU times: user 320 ms, sys: 312 ms, total: 632 ms
Wall time: 209 ms
In [3]: %time y2 = func_einsum(C, X)
CPU times: user 844 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 844 ms
Wall time: 842 ms
In [4]: %time y3 = func_einsum2(C, X)
CPU times: user 292 ms, sys: 44 ms, total: 336 ms
Wall time: 334 ms
```

When I increase `K` to 200, the differences are more extreme:

```
In [2]: %time y1= func_dot(C, X)
CPU times: user 4.5 s, sys: 1.02 s, total: 5.52 s
Wall time: 2.3 s
In [3]: %time y2= func_einsum(C, X)
CPU times: user 1min 16s, sys: 44 ms, total: 1min 16s
Wall time: 1min 16s
In [4]: %time y3 = func_einsum2(C, X)
CPU times: user 15.3 s, sys: 312 ms, total: 15.6 s
Wall time: 15.6 s
```

Can someone explain why einsum is so much slower here?

If it matters, here is my numpy config:

```
In [6]: np.show_config()
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
atlas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_WITHOUT_LAPACK', None)]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"None\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
atlas_blas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"None\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_WITHOUT_LAPACK', None)]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: I've noticed the same thing when comparing `np.einsum` to `np.tensordot`. I suspect that this may just be the price you pay for generality - `np.dot` calls BLAS subroutines (`dgemm` etc.) that are very highly optimised for the special case of dot products between two matrices, whereas `np.einsum` deals with all sorts of scenarios potentially involving multiple input matrices. I'm not sure of the exact details, but I suspect that it would be difficult to design `np.einsum` to make fully optimal use of BLAS in all such cases.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can have the best of both worlds:

```
def func_dot_einsum(C, X):
    Y = X.dot(C)
    return np.einsum('ij,ij->i', Y, X)
```

On my system:

```
In [7]: %timeit func_dot(C, X)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.1 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit func_einsum(C, X)
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit func_einsum2(C, X)
10 loops, best of 3: 43.5 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit func_dot_einsum(C, X)
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop
```

When available, `np.dot` uses BLAS, MKL, or whatever library you have . So the call to `np.dot` is almost certainly being multithreaded. `np.einsum` has its own loops, so doesn't use any of those optimizations, apart from its own use of SIMD to speed things up over a vanilla C implementation.

---

Then there's the multi-input einsum call that runs much slower... The numpy source for einsum is very complex and I don't fully understand it. So be advised that the following is speculative at best, but here's what I think is going on...

When you run something like `np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b)`, the benefit over doing `np.sum(a*b, axis=1)` comes from avoiding having to instantiate the intermediate array with all the products, and looping twice over it. So at the low level what goes on is something like:

```
for i in range(I):
    out[i] = 0
    for j in range(J):
        out[i] += a[i, j] * b[i, j]
```

Say now that you are after something like:

```
np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i', a, b, c)
```

You could do the same operation as

```
np.sum(a[:, :, None] * b[None, :, :] * c[:, None, :], axis=(1, 2))
```

And what I think einsum does is to run this last code without having to instantiate the huge intermediate array, which certainly makes things faster:

```
In [29]: a, b, c = np.random.rand(3, 100, 100)

In [30]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i', a, b, c)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.41 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit np.sum(a[:, :, None] * b[None, :, :] * c[:, None, :], axis=(1, 2))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
```

But if you look at it carefully, getting rid of intermediate storage can be a terrible thing. This is what I think einsum is doing at the low level:

```
for i in range(I):
    out[i] = 0
    for j in range(J):
        for k in range(K):
            out[i] += a[i, j] * b[j, k] * c[i, k]
```

But you are repeating a ton of operations! If you instead did:

```
for i in range(I):
    out[i] = 0
    for j in range(J):
        temp = 0
        for k in range(K):
            temp += b[j, k] * c[i, k]
        out[i] += a[i, j] * temp
```

you would be doing `I * J * (K-1)` less multiplications (and `I * J` extra additions), and save yourself a ton of time. My guess is that einsum is not smart enough to optimize things at this level. In the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6f9a41276153187a4c6e45eb0b8a9999d946608d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src#L3027) there is a hint that it only optimizes operations with 1 or 2 operands, not 3. In any case automating this for general inputs seems like anything but simple...

Comment: I had ended up at a dot-einsum solution as well but was hoping something using just einsum would be faster. Your answer explains nicely why it isn't. Thanks.

Comment: Update: in numpy >= 1.12.0, there is a named argument "optimize" that will tell numpy to do the optimization. The reason it's not default is memory issues (and maybe backwards compatibility).

Comment: Adding `optimize=True` within the example above: `%timeit np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i', a, b, c)` takes the time from **2.4 ms** down to **410 µs** !

Answer (score 6):

`einsum` has a specialized case for '2 operands, ndim=2'.  In this case there are 3 operands, and a total of 3 dimensions.  So it has to use a general `nditer`.

While trying to understand how the string input is parsed, I wrote a pure Python einsum simulator, https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum/blob/master/einsum_py.py

The (stripped down) einsum and sum-of-products functions are:

```
def myeinsum(subscripts, *ops, **kwargs):
    # dropin preplacement for np.einsum (more or less)
    <parse subscript strings>
    <prepare op_axes>
    x = sum_of_prod(ops, op_axes, **kwargs)
    return x

def sum_of_prod(ops, op_axes,...):
    ...
    it = np.nditer(ops, flags, op_flags, op_axes)
    it.operands[nop][...] = 0
    it.reset()
    for (x,y,z,w) in it:
        w[...] += x*y*z
    return it.operands[nop]
```

Debugging output for `myeinsum('ik,km,im->i',X,C,X,debug=True)` with `(M,K)=(10,5)`

```
{'max_label': 109, 
 'min_label': 105, 
 'nop': 3, 
 'shapes': [(10, 5), (5, 5), (10, 5)], 
 ....}}
 ...
iter labels: [105, 107, 109],'ikm'

op_axes [[0, 1, -1], [-1, 0, 1], [0, -1, 1], [0, -1, -1]]
```

If you write a `sum-of-prod` function like this in `cython` you should get something close to the generalized `einsum`.

With the full `(M,K)`, this simulated einsum is 6-7x slower.

---

Some timings building on the other answers:

```
In [84]: timeit np.dot(X,C)
1 loops, best of 3: 781 ms per loop

In [85]: timeit np.einsum('ik,km->im',X,C)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.28 s per loop

In [86]: timeit np.einsum('im,im->i',A,X)
10 loops, best of 3: 163 ms per loop
```

This `'im,im->i' step is substantially faster than the other.  The sum dimension,`m`is only 20.  I suspect`einsum` is treating this as a special case.

```
In [87]: timeit np.einsum('im,im->i',np.dot(X,C),X)
1 loops, best of 3: 950 ms per loop

In [88]: timeit np.einsum('im,im->i',np.einsum('ik,km->im',X,C),X)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.45 s per loop
```

The times for these composite calculations are simply sums of the corresponding pieces.