# How to write this numpy code in vectorized form?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I have the following function in python which I am not able to figure out how to express in vectorized form.
For me, cov is a numpy array of shape (2,2), mu is the mean vector with shape (2,) and xtp is of shape (~50000,2).
I know scipy provides scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf but I am trying to learn how to write efficient vectorized code. Please

```
def mvnpdf(xtp, mu, cov):
    temp = np.zeros(xtp.shape[0])
    i = 0
    length = xtp.shape[0]
    const = 1 / ( ((2* np.pi)**(len(mu)/2)) * (np.linalg.det(cov)**(1/2)) )
    inv = np.linalg.inv(cov)
    while i < length:
        x = xtp[i]-mu
        exponent = (-1/2) * (x.dot(inv).dot(x))
        temp[i] =  (const * np.exp(exponent))
        i+=1
    return temp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only tricky part to vectorize is that double `.dot`.  Let's isolate that:

```
x = xtp - mu  # move this out of the loop
ddot = [i.dot(inv).dot(i) for i in x]
temp = const * np.exp(-0.5 * ddot)
```

Put that in your code and see if it produces that same thing.

There are several ways of 'vectorizing' a `dot`.  The one I like to try first is `einsum`.  In my tests this is equivalent:

```
ddot = np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',x,inv,x)
```

I'd suggest trying it to see if it works and speeds things up.  And do play around with these calculations with smaller arrays (not the ~50000) in an interactive shell.

I'm testing things with

```
In [225]: x
Out[225]: 
array([[  0.,   2.],
       [  1.,   3.],
       ...
       [  7.,   9.],
       [  8.,  10.],
       [  9.,  11.]])
In [226]: inv
Out[226]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Since this is a learning exercise I'll leave the details to you.

With `(2,2)`, the calculations one `cov` might be faster it done explicitely rather than with the `det` and `inv` functions.  But it's that `length` iteration that's the time consumer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. einsum looks awesome. The resulting code is a lot faster .Any good resources to learn on using enisum?

Comment: @enitihas: there are relatively few resources scattered around the web, but here's a SO question with some answers and links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-einsum-numpy