# How to vectorize np.dot(vector_a, vector_b[:,i]) for i in range?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, dot-product

I have a numpy array vector_a of shape (3,1). If I multiply it with a vector_b of shape (1,3) I get a result of shape (3,3).

Now, vector_b is actually an (3,N) numpy array of column vectors. I want to multiply each of these column vectors by vector_a to produce N 3x3 matrices, result of shape (N,3,3)

I have done the following:

```
r = np.dot(vector_a.reshape(1,3,1), vector_b.T.reshape(N, 1, 3))
```

and I was expecting r to be of shape (N,3,3) but I got a shape of (1,3,64,3)??? I don't know why I'm getting this shape. Both vector_a and vector_b are C contiguous. I tried to convert vector_b to F contiguous before doing the `vector_b.T.reshape(N, 1, 3)` but I still get the same r shape (1,3,64,3).

Does anybody know how to write the right expression?

Comment: What does `dot` say about arrays that are larger than 2d?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read that. But I still can't get it to work...

Comment: This really isn't a `dot` case.  The `einsum` expression does not sum anything.  It can be done with plain multiplication (and broadcasting) `b.T[:,:,None] * a.T[None,:,:]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative solution, if you use [`einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), you can avoid having to reshape the array for the dot product:

```
np.einsum('ij,jk->kij', vector_a, vector_b)
```

Comment: I still need to fully understand einsum, but this works! thanks

Comment: No problem! `einsum` is incredibly useful - there are various answers explaining it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum) (including one I wrote ;-)).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`ndarray.T`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) -

```
vector_b.T[:,None,:]*vector_a
```