# Python Numpy nested loop - fast way to calculate?

Tags: python, loops, numpy

In the following summation:

[image]

I need to replace s(dot product) with the following:

[image]

My code, which is extremely slow:

```
    summing = 0

    update = np.zeros((5172,))

    for index, xi in enumerate(x_v1):
        yval = y[index]
        kernel_sum = 0
        for index_val, x_val in enumerate(x_v1):
            kernel_sum += update[index_val] *(np.dot(x_val, xi.transpose()) + 1)**2
        dot_product = kernel_sum
        dot_product = np.clip(dot_product, -20, 20)



        summing += yval * np.log(sigmoid(dot_product)) + (1-yval)* np.log(1-sigmoid(dot_product))
```

How can I make this faster?

Comment: Have you looked at using [`numpy.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)?  [Here's a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum) explaning to use it.

Comment: If your code is working and you need some hints on how to improve it, you might want to move such question to CodeReview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should completely remove the for-loop ("vectorize the code", as they say in Matlab...). The best way to do this is to first formulate your equations in matrix form and then try to write them using numpy only.

For example, you can compute your entire quadratic kernel using only numpy operations as follows:

```
K = (x_v1.dot(x_v1.T) + rho) ** 2
```

which will already reduce the computation time substantially.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457849/building-a-decision-tree