# Building a Decision Tree

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

When building a decision tree, at each node, we select the best feature, and then the best splitting position for that feature.
However, when all values for the best feature is 0 for samples in the current node /set, what do I do? All samples keep being grouped to one side (the <= 0 branch), and an infinite loop occurs.
For example:

```
#left: 1500, #right: 0
```

then,

```
#left: 1500, #right: 0
```

and so on...

Just for reference, I'm following the following pseudo-code.

```
GrowTree(S)
if (y_i = C for all i in S and some class C) then {
 return new leaf(C)                             
 } else {
 choose best splitting feature j and splitting point beta (*)
 I choose the one that gives me the max entropy drop
 S_l = {i : X_ij < beta}                           
 S_r = {i : X_ij >= beta}
 return new node(j, beta, GrowTree(S_l), GrowTree(S_r))
```

}

Comment: Can you show us your code for building the tree?

Comment: "However, when all values for the best feature is 0 for samples". it seems like all samples reaching this node are of the same class (can you check?). if so, the node is useless and should not have been created.

Comment: If the code you provide is not python, why tag python? Seems incidental

Comment: @TomerLevinboim You are right. What I described is only possible when all samples in the node have the same value (0) for all features. I was considering splits incorrectly. I was only supposed to consider splits where the left and right split values are different. So, for 0,0,0,1,1,2, I was checking 5 potential splits instead of only 2.

Comment: @TomerLevinboim: I'm doing spam detection using the above decision tree. The only features I currently have are a few word counts. Can you explain how "bag of words" can be used as a feature? Do I add a feature that is a probability or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply impossible. You are supposed to select threshold which leads to the biggest incrase of model certainty. Using threshold which puts every single instance in the same branch gives you 0 increase in models certainty, thus this is **not the best split**.  This should happen if and only if, the impurity/entropy is already 0 in this feature, but then it is a stopping criterion for creating leaves in decision tree.

Comment: I'm doing spam detection using the above decision tree. The only features I currently have are a few word counts. Can you explain how "bag of words" can be used as a feature? Do I include/add a feature that is a probability or something?

Comment: Ask a separate question

Comment: Just did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469548/bag-of-words-feature-for-spam-detection-decision-tree