# Given a List of Matrices, Sum Them but Ignore Some Matrix's Rows

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

As an example, let

```
A = np.array([[a1, a2],
              [a3, a4]])
B = np.array([[b1, b2],
              [b3, b4]])
C = np.array([[c1, c2],
              [c3, c4]]),
```

let `l = [A, B, C]`, and let

```
I = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1]]).
```

I want to calculate the Matrix R

```
R = np.array([[a1 + c1, a2 + c2],
              [b3 + c3, b4 + c4]])
```

---

I.e. in general, I have a list of `k` `nxm` matrices stored in `l` and an index matrix `I` of dimensions `nxk` that specifies for *each row* of the result `R` which of the `k` matrices in `l` should be used in the calculation of that row of `R`. Above, the first row of `I` is `[1, 0, 1]` and thus `A` and `C` are used in the calculation of the first row of `R`.

Which `numpy` function can I use for this?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with numpy to give a complete solution but it seems like you should be able to reshape your data so that this becomes a simple multiplication operation between the coefficients matrix and the terms matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `l` as the input list of `(n,m)` shaped arrays, you can use the very efficient [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,jik->ik',I,l)
```

Sample run -

```
In [75]: # Inputs
    ...: a1,a2,a3,a4 = 4,6,8,2
    ...: b1,b2,b3,b4 = 5,11,4,3
    ...: c1,c2,c3,c4 = 6,99,2,5
    ...: 
    ...: A = np.array([[a1, a2],
    ...:               [a3, a4]])
    ...: B = np.array([[b1, b2],
    ...:               [b3, b4]])
    ...: C = np.array([[c1, c2],
    ...:               [c3, c4]])
    ...: l = [A,B,C]
    ...: 
    ...: I = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
    ...:               [0, 1, 1]])
    ...: # Expected output
    ...: R = np.array([[a1 + c1, a2 + c2],
    ...:               [b3 + c3, b4 + c4]])
    ...: 

In [76]: R
Out[76]: 
array([[ 10, 105],
       [  6,   8]])

In [77]: np.einsum('ij,jik->ik',I,l)
Out[77]: 
array([[ 10, 105],
       [  6,   8]])
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know about `einsum`. Would you care to explain `ij, jik → ik`?

Comment: @fabian789 Basically we are elementwise multiplying the input arrays with `axis=0` from `I` aligned with `axis=1` from `l` and `axis=1` from `I` aligned with `axis=0` from `l`. Then, sum-reducing the first axis of the multiplication result. All of this is done in one efficient step with that einsum call. For more info, please refer to this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum

Comment: Cool! I am accepting this as it seems to be the most general. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
terms = np.array([A, B, C])  # A,B,C are 2x2 matrices
coeffs = np.array([[1,0,1], [0,1,1]])
```

You can do:

```
# transpose terms to 2x2 matrix of [A,B,C] element vectors,
# with shape (2,2,3):
transposed_terms = np.transpose(terms, (1,2,0)) 
# tile coefficients to align:
tiled_coeffs = np.tile(coeffs, 2).reshape(2,2,3)
# element-wise multiplication and sum over last dimension
return np.sum(transposed_terms, tiled_coeffs, 2)
```

There's probably a simpler way to do this using something like [numpy.tensordot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), but my numpy-fu is not strong enough for this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Avish that this is very much like a matrix multiplication but in the end you just want the diagonal entries:

```
np.diagonal(l.T.dot(I.T).T).T
```

How it works:

`l.T` will give `[[a1, b1, c1], [a3, b3, c3], [a2, b2, c2], [a4, b4, c4]]`

`l.T.dot(I.T)` will give `[[[a1+c1, b1+c1], [a3+c3, b3+c3]], [[a2+c2, b2+c2], [a4+c4, b4+c4]]]`

`l.T.dot(I.T).T` is `[[[a1+c1, a2+c2], [a3+c3, a4+c4]], [[b1+c1, b2+c2], [b3+c3, b4+c4]]]`

And the diagonal entries (`np.diagonal(l.T.dot(I.T).T)`) are `[[a1+c1, b3+c3], [a2+c2, b4+c4]]`

Finally, its transpose is: `[[a1+c1, a2+c2], [b3+c3, b4+c4]]`