# How to do matrix vector inner products for each pair separate in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

Lets say, I have bunch of matrices As and vectors bs.

```
As = array([[[1, 7], [3, 8]],
            [[2, 1], [5, 9]],
            [[7, 2], [8, 3]]])
bs = array([[8, 0], [8, 8], [7, 3]])
```

When I do np.inner(As, bs), I get:

```
array([[[  8,  64,  28], [ 24,  88,  45]],
       [[ 16,  24,  17], [ 40, 112,  62]],
       [[ 56,  72,  55], [ 64,  88,  65]]])
```

But I do not need all inner products. What I want is, to calculate each matrix with each vector once.
I can do something like this:

```
np.array(map(lambda (a, b): np.inner(a, b), zip(As, bs)))
```

Then I get the expected matrix:

```
array([[  8,  24], [ 24, 112], [ 55,  65]])
```

Now I do not want to use zip, map etc. because I need this operation > 10**6 time (for image processing, exactly for GMM).
Is there any way to use numpy, scipy etc. that can do this for me? (fast and efficent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',As, bs)
```

**Explanation**

With `np.array(map(lambda (a, b): np.inner(a, b), zip(As, bs)))`, we are selecting the first element off `As` as `a` and off `bs` as `b` and doing inner product. Thus, we are doing :

```
In [19]: np.inner(As[0],bs[0])
Out[19]: array([ 8, 24])

In [20]: np.inner(As[1],bs[1])
Out[20]: array([ 24, 112])

In [21]: np.inner(As[2],bs[2])
Out[21]: array([55, 65])
```

Think of it as a loop, we iterate 3 times, corresponding to the length of first axis of `As`, which is same as for `bs`. Thus, looking at the `lambda` expression, at each iteration, we have `a = As[0] & b = bs[0]`, `a = As[1] & b = bs[1]` and so on.

`As` and `bs` being `3D` and `2D`, let's represent them as iterators imagining the inner-product in our *minds*. Thus, at iteration, we would have `a : j,k` and `b : m`. With that inner product between `a` and `b`, we would lose the second axis of `a` and first of `b`. Thus, we need to align `k` with `m`. Thus, we could assume `b` to have the same iterator as `k`. Referencing back from `a` to `As` and `b` to `bs`, in essence, we would lose the third axis from `As` and second from `bs` with the inner product/sum-reduction. That iterating along the first axis for `As` and `bs` signifies that we need to keep those aligned under these sum-reductions.

Let's summarize.

We have the iterators involved for the input arrays like so -

```
As :  i x j x k 
bs :  i x k
```

Steps involved in the intended operation :

- Keep the first axis of `As` aligned with first of `bs`.
- Lose the third axis of `As` with sum-reduction against second of `bs`.

Thus, we would be left with the iterators `i,j` for the output.

`np.einsum` is a pretty efficient implementation and is specially handy when we need to keep one or more of the axes of the input arrays aligned against each other.

For more info on `einsum`, I would suggest following the docs link supplied earlier and also [`this Q&A`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum) could be helpful!

Comment: @PiMathCLanguage Added some comments to help out. Check those out.