# Matrix multiplication of inner dimensions of 3D tensors?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two `numpy` matrices of dimension `(386, 3, 4)` and `(386, 4, 3)`. I want to produce an output dimension of `(386, 3, 3)`. In other words, I wish to execute the following loop in a vectorized fashion -

```
for i in range(len(input1)):
    output[i] = np.matmul(input1[i], input2[i])
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is what `matmul` was created for - without the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to keep the first axes aligned, so I would suggest using an approach with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',input1,input2)
```

Sample run to verify shapes -

```
In [106]: a = np.random.rand(386, 3, 4)

In [107]: b = np.random.rand(386, 4, 3)

In [108]: np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',a,b).shape
Out[108]: (386, 3, 3)
```

Sample run to verify values on smaller input -

```
In [174]: a = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4)

In [175]: b = np.random.rand(2, 4, 3)

In [176]: output = np.zeros((2,3,3))

In [177]: for i in range(len(a)):
     ...:     output[i] = np.matmul(a[i], b[i])
     ...:     

In [178]: output
Out[178]: 
array([[[ 1.43473795,  0.860279  ,  1.17855877],
        [ 1.91036828,  1.23063125,  1.5319063 ],
        [ 1.06489098,  0.86868941,  0.84986621]],

       [[ 1.07178572,  1.020091  ,  0.63070531],
        [ 1.34033495,  1.26641131,  0.79911685],
        [ 1.68916831,  1.63009854,  1.14612462]]])

In [179]: np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',a,b)
Out[179]: 
array([[[ 1.43473795,  0.860279  ,  1.17855877],
        [ 1.91036828,  1.23063125,  1.5319063 ],
        [ 1.06489098,  0.86868941,  0.84986621]],

       [[ 1.07178572,  1.020091  ,  0.63070531],
        [ 1.34033495,  1.26641131,  0.79911685],
        [ 1.68916831,  1.63009854,  1.14612462]]])
```

Sample run to verify values on bigger input -

```
In [180]: a = np.random.rand(386, 3, 4)

In [181]: b = np.random.rand(386, 4, 3)

In [182]: output = np.zeros((386,3,3))

In [183]: for i in range(len(a)):
     ...:     output[i] = np.matmul(a[i], b[i])
     ...:     

In [184]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',a,b), output)
Out[184]: True
```

Comment: Ah! It's high time I learn `einsum()`. I've been running from it for quite some time. Do you have a quick tutorial for it? Thanks!

Comment: @martianwars See if this helps out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum

Comment: I don't think I'm getting identical results when compared with `np.matmul`. There are slight differences

Comment: @martianwars Added samples runs to verify values as well.

Comment: I get `allclose` as `True`, but on printing them out, the values are slightly different

Comment: @martianwars How different are they? At what precision are they differing?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GS92pe4U. I see an identical problem when I use @PaulPanzer's solution

Comment: @martianwars Well in floating pt operations, those of the orders of `1E-15` could be ignored(at least I would). Those `1E-14` might be worth a look,  can't pinpoint anything in specific on those. Just curious, is that order of precision really important?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter in my application. Just wondering. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`matmul` also works:

```
a = np.random.random((243,3,4))
b = np.random.random((243,4,3))
np.matmul(a,b).shape
# (243, 3, 3)
```