# Using numpy.einsum for transpose times matrix: x^T * x

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

For a 2D matrix `X` (shape `(m,n)`), I'm trying to calculate `X.T * X` where `*` is matrix multiplication.  [Following the explanation on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641428/230468) I expected to be able to do this using, `np.einsum('ji,ik->jk', X, X)` where on the LHS writing `ji` first takes the transpose of the first `X` argument, then multiplies it by the second `X` argument.

This doesn't work with the error (for `(m,n) = (3,4)`):

> `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (4,3)->(4,newaxis,3) (4,3)->(3,4)`

This works however: `np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', X.T, X)`.  What am I missing here?  Why is it even adding an axis in the middle anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `X.T * X` (* being matrix-multiplication), you are sum-reducing the second axis of first `X's transpose` against the first axis of second `X`. Now, second axis of first `X's transpose` would be same as the first axis of first `X`. Thus, we are simply sum-reducing the first axis from those two `X's`, while the remaining axes from them stay on.

To replicate that on `einsum`, keep the first character in the string-notation same, while different ones for the second axis of the two inputs, like so -

```
np.einsum('ji,jk->ik', X, X)
```

Thus, `j's` are sum-reduced, while the remaining axes - `i` and `k` remain in the output.

Again, this would be slower than the native matrix-multiplication : `X.T.dot(X)`. But, I am guessing this post is meant more as a learning one for `einsum`.

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  In matrix-multiplication, `A x B`, we want each *row* of `A` multiplied by each *column* of `B`, right?   So `'ji,jk->ik'` makes it seem like we're taking a *row* of the transpose, and multiplying by a *row* of the matrix... no?

Comment: Nevermind... just confused.  This makes sense, thanks @Divakar!