# Using numpy einsum to compute inner product of column-vectors of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, numpy-einsum

Suppose I have a numpy matrix like this:

```
[[   1    2    3]
 [  10  100 1000]]
```

I would like to compute the inner product of each column with itself, so the result would be:

```
[1*1 + 10*10    2*2 + 100*100    3*3 + 1000*1000] == [101, 10004, 1000009]
```

I would like to know if this is possible using the [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum) function (and to better understand it).

So far, the closest result I could have is:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [10, 100, 1000]])

res = np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', arr, arr)

# [[    101    1002   10003]
#  [   1002   10004  100006]
#  [  10003  100006 1000009]]
```

The diagonal contains the expected result, but I would like to know if I can avoid edge calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->j',arr,arr)
```

Sample run -

```
In [243]: np.einsum('ij,ij->j',arr,arr)
Out[243]: array([    101,   10004, 1000009])
```

Or with `np.sum` -

```
In [244]: (arr**2).sum(0)
Out[244]: array([    101,   10004, 1000009])
```

Or with [`numexpr` module](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#how-it-works) -

```
In [248]: import numexpr as ne

In [249]: ne.evaluate('sum(arr**2,0)')
Out[249]: array([    101,   10004, 1000009])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're expecting here can be understood intuitively, with one intermediate step from [Divakar's einsum answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48066913/2956066).

```
In [19]: arr
Out[19]: 
array([[   1,    2,    3],
       [  10,  100, 1000]])

# simply take element-wise product with the array itself
In [20]: np.einsum('ij, ij -> ij', arr, arr)
Out[20]: 
array([[      1,       4,       9],
       [    100,   10000, 1000000]])
```

But, this doesn't give the result that you expected. So, if you observe the above result, we just need to *sum along the first dimension* (i.e. axis 0). So, we omit the subscript `i` after `->` in the einsum result, which means we ask it to sum along that axis, and that yields the expected result which is:

```
In [21]: np.einsum('ij, ij -> j', arr, arr)
Out[21]: array([    101,   10004, 1000009])
```

---

P.S. Also, for a general understanding of [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), see the detailed discussion here: [understanding-numpy-einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47966452/2956066)