# How most efficiently compute the diagonal of a matrix product

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, pytorch, linear-algebra

I want to compute the following:

```
import numpy as np
n= 3
m = 2
x = np.random.randn(n,m)

#Method 1
y = np.zeros(m)
for i in range(m):
    y[i] = x[:,i] @ x[:,i]

#Method 2
y2 = np.diag(x.T @ x)
```

The first method has the problem that it uses a for loop, which can't be very effecient (I need to do this in pytorch on a GPU millions of times)

The second method computes the full matrix product, when I only need the diagonal entries, so that can't be very efficient either.

I'm wondering whether there exist any clever way of doing this?

Comment: With `np.einsum` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066890/

Comment: @Divakar. I'd argue that that's overkill, although it probably creates fewer temp arrays than the trivial solution I posted.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why would it be overkill?

Comment: @Divakar. Because it's not as obvious (to me), and I wasn't really thinking about it. I've close the question since your answer already covers all the reasonable solutions I could think of.

Comment: Well yeah without the need of temp arrays lends itself to an efficient solution as well with `einsum`.

Comment: `(x.T[:,None,:]@(x.T[:,:,None]))[:,0,0]` may be a bit faster, though it looks a lot messier.  `@` broadcasts on the first of 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Use a manually constructed sum-product. You want the sums of the squares of the individual columns:

```
y = (x * x).sum(axis=0)
```

As Divakar suggests, [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) will likely offer a less memory-intensive option, since it does not require the temporary array `x * x`:

```
y = np.einsum('ij,ij->j', x, x)
```