# Numpy - multiply 3D array(100,100,3) with 2D array(100,100)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I am solving quite trivial problem. I can solve it through iteration, but its too slow.

My problem:

```
import numpy as np
arr3 = np.zeros(shape=[4, 4, 3])
arr2 = np.zeros(shape=[4, 4])

#This is ok but I dont want
arr3[0,0]*arr2[0,0] # thats [0,0,0]*0
#This is not ok but I need
arr3[:,:]*arr2
```

Simply said, i need to multiply each element from arr3[:][:] which are in format [R,G,B]) with corresponding element in arr2 which are in float (distance) and all without iteration

Thanks

Comment: `arr[:,:]` doesn't do anything for you.  `arr3 * arr2[:,:,None]` adds a dimensionof `arr2` and allows them to broadcast together.

Comment: Not sure what your intended result is. Can you provide your iteration-code to make the logic clear?

Comment: hpaulj, thanks, thats exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

This operation is called *Hadamard product* (i.e. element-wise product of two arrays). But, for this operation both arrays have to be of the same dimension. Thus, you've to *promote* the 2D array to 3D and then you can use simple `*` or [`numpy.einsum()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47966452/2956066) as in:

```
In [11]: arr3 = np.arange(4*4*3).reshape(4, 4, 3)
    ...: arr2 = np.arange(4*4).reshape(4, 4)

In [12]: np.einsum('ijk, ijk -> ijk', arr3, arr2[..., np.newaxis])
Out[12]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  3,   4,   5],
        [ 12,  14,  16],
        [ 27,  30,  33]],

       [[ 48,  52,  56],
        [ 75,  80,  85],
        [108, 114, 120],
        [147, 154, 161]],

       [[192, 200, 208],
        [243, 252, 261],
        [300, 310, 320],
        [363, 374, 385]],

       [[432, 444, 456],
        [507, 520, 533],
        [588, 602, 616],
        [675, 690, 705]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just expand the dimensions of the smaller array to allow for [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

This can be done e.g by using `np.newaxis`:

```
import numpy as np
arr3 = np.zeros(shape=[4, 4, 3])
arr2 = np.zeros(shape=[4, 4])

res = arr3 * arr2[..., np.newaxis])
```

(This is identical to what @hpaulj suggested, `None` and `np.newaxis` do the same thing.)

This will change the shape to of the smaller array to `(4,4,1)` and apply it along each entry along the last axis of the larger array.