# Sequentially applying a dot product to slices of 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, dot-product, numpy-slicing

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I have a 3D numpy array `Rp` of shape 4x4x701, where each of the 701 4x4 slices represents a certain quantity at a different point in time. I'm trying to efficiently apply a Givens rotation matrix `Q` and its Hermitian transpose `QH` to each of the 701 slices, and am currently doing it iteratively, like so:

```
for idx in np.arange(Rp.shape[-1]):
    Rp[[j,k],:,idx] = np.dot(Q, Rp[[j,k],:,idx])
    Rp[:,[j,k],idx] = np.dot(Rp[:,[j,k],idx], QH)
```

but there must be a way to do this NOT iteratively (for the numpy speedup). I realise I can just use `np.dot` for the first case, but this won't work for the second without some transposition, which seems like it would slow things down.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: numpy transposition is in a sense a notational convenience. It doesn't actually reorder an array in memory. So it's not actually slow. It's the correct way to vectorise your code. Have you tried timing your solution?

Comment: I would suggest trying out the operations you want with a 1d vector and a 2d array first and I bet you would probably be able to figure it out. You can most definitely achieve this with some clever usage of `np.einsum()`. I would suggest perusing [this blog post](http://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/) (which inspired [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641428/5087436)). But you can also transpose as you like for vectorized operations---the loop is what's killing you, not transposition.

Comment: `matmul` (the @ operator) does the `dot` on the last 2 dimensions.  So if your `Rp` was (701,4,4) shape, you could probably do something like `Q @ Rp @ QH`.  I'll have test for details.

Comment: @Denziloe thank you, that is a vital piece of information to have. I will try do it with the transpose now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough test for shapes; values really should be more diagnostic:

```
In [46]: Q = np.eye(4); QH = np.conj(Q)
In [47]: R = np.ones((10,4,4))

In [48]: (Q @ R @ QH).shape
Out[48]: (10, 4, 4)

In [49]: np.einsum('ij,kjl,lm->kil',Q,R,QH).shape
Out[49]: (10, 4, 4)
```

---

If the big dimension is last:

```
In [50]: Rp = R.transpose(1,2,0)
In [51]: Rp.shape
Out[51]: (4, 4, 10)

In [53]: np.einsum('ij,jlk,lm->ilk',Q,Rp,QH).shape
Out[53]: (4, 4, 10)

In [55]: (Q @ Rp.transpose(2,1,0) @ QH).transpose(1,2,0).shape
Out[55]: (4, 4, 10)
```

We could also write this with `tensordot`.

```
In [58]: np.tensordot(QH,np.tensordot(Q,Rp,(1,1)),(0,1)).shape
Out[58]: (4, 4, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this example. Would you please be able to explain your use of tensordot?

Comment: `tensordot` uses transpose and reshape to convert the arrays into ones that it can pass to `dot` - and reshapes back as needed.