# How to use broadcasting with my numpy arrays (3000,3) and (3,2,3000)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, tensor, broadcasting

I have 2 arrays currently with shapes v1=(3000,3) and v2=(3,2,3000). The 3000 is a time dimension so v1 has 3000 (1,3) samples and v2 has 3000 (3,2) samples. I wish to do matrix multiplication and broadcast along the 3000 dimension so that I get 3000 (1,2) vectors in return.

I have tried reshaping so that v1 = (1,3,3000) and v2 = (3,2,300) which gives an error saying that the shapes are not aligned.

code:

```
v1 = np.ones((1,3,3000)) +1
v2 = np.ones((3,2,3000)) - 0.5
np.dot(v1,v2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `v1` of shape `(3000,3)` and `v2` as `(3,2,3000)`, we can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,jki->ik',v1,v2)
```

This gives us an output of shape `(3000,2)`.

We could play around with the `optimize` arg in `np.einsum`. With `optimize = True`, it leverages `BLAS` internally and with `optimize = False` resorts to simple C-loops. That `BLAS` way requires some setting up work too. So, with decent lengths of axes that undergo sum-reductions, we might want to set that flag as `True` and `False` otherwise. In this case, it seems those axes are really short, so we are probably better off with the default : `optimize = False` input.

Comment: is this equivalent to doing matrix multiplication? I tried to read the docs on einsum but they puzzled me.

Comment: @seanysull It's performing matrix multiplication on tensors(more than 2 dims) under the hoods leveraging BLAS with that optimize flag set as True, same as `np.dot`.

Comment: @Divakar Do you know the reason why using `optimize=True` consumes more time than when not using it? (please see the timings in my code below). Could it be possible that it spends lot of time optimizing the code?

Comment: @kmario23 What version of NumPy are you on?

Comment: @Divakar sure, I'm using `'1.16.1'`

Comment: @You are right. Edited question with comments on the same. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to not use `optimize=True` flag because it's in-efficient, for some strange reason. Also, I'd recommend you to explicitly *promote* the 2D-array to 3D, perform **batch matrix multiplication** and then squeeze the singleton dimension of the resultant array, if you at the end need a 2D array as the final result. Please find the code below:

```
# sample arrays
In [25]: v1 = np.random.random_sample((3000, 3))
In [26]: v2 = np.random.random_sample((3, 2, 3000))

# Divakar's approach
In [27]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,jki->ik',v1,v2, optimize=True)
80.7 µs ± 792 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# needed for future use
In [28]: res_optimized = np.einsum('ij,jki->ik',v1,v2, optimize=True)

# promoting to 3D array and swapping axes
In [29]: v1 = v1[:, np.newaxis, :]
In [30]: v2 = np.moveaxis(v2, 2, 0)

# perform batch matrix multiplication
In [31]: %timeit np.einsum("bij, bjk -> bik", v1, v2)
47.9 µs ± 496 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# for sanity checking
In [32]: res = np.einsum("bij, bjk -> bik", v1, v2)

In [33]: res.shape, res_optimized.shape
Out[33]: ((3000, 1, 2), (3000, 2))

# squeeze the singleton dimension and perform sanity check with Divakar's approach
In [34]: np.allclose(res.squeeze(), res_optimized)
Out[34]: True
```

So, as we can see from the above timings, we gain approx. 2x speedup by not using `optimize=True` flag. Also, explicitly shaping the arrays to 3D gives bit more understanding about what's going on when we use `numpy.einsum()`.

Note: timings were performed using the latest NumPy version `'1.16.1'`

---

P.S. Read more about [Understanding NumPy einsum()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47966452)