# numpy broadcasting to each column of the matrix separately

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have to matrices:

```
a = np.array([[6],[3],[4]])
b = np.array([1,10])
```

when I do:

```
c = a * b
```

c looks like this:

```
[ 6, 60]
[ 3, 30]
[ 4, 40]
```

which is good. 
now, lets say I add a column to a (for the sake of the example its an identical column. but it dosent have to be):

```
a = np.array([[6,6],[3,3],[4,4]])
```

b stayes the same.

the result I want is 2 identical copies of c (since the column are identical), stacked along a new axis:

```
new_c.shape == [3,2,2]
```

when if u do `new_c[:,:,0]` or `new_c[:,:,1]` you get the original c. 
I tried adding new axes to both a and b using `np.expand_dims` but it did not help.

Comment: First case a (3,1) * (2,) => (3,2).  2nd, (3,2)*(2,)=>(3,2)*(1,2)=>(3,2).  You want (3,2,1)*(1,1,2)=(3,2,2).  `a[:,:,None]` should do the trick.

Comment: or maybe its (3,1,n)*(1,2,1)>(3,2n) a[:,None,:]*b[None,2,None]

Answer (score 1):

One way is using **`numpy.einsum`**:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[6],[3],[4]])
>>> b = np.array([1,10])
>>> print(a * b)
[[ 6 60]
 [ 3 30]
 [ 4 40]]
```

```py
>>> print(np.einsum('ij, j -> ij', a, b))
[[ 6 60]
 [ 3 30]
 [ 4 40]]
```

```py
>>> a = np.array([[6,6],[3,3],[4,4]])
>>> print(np.einsum('ij, k -> ikj', a, b)[:, :, 0])
>>> print(np.einsum('ij, k -> ikj', a, b)[:, :, 1])
[[ 6 60]
 [ 3 30]
 [ 4 40]]
[[ 6 60]
 [ 3 30]
 [ 4 40]]
```

For more usage about **`numpy.einsum`**, I recommend:

[Understanding NumPy's einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here, one of which is using `numpy.einsum` as explained in the other answer. Another possibility is using array `reshape` method:

```
result = a.T.reshape((a.shape[1], a.shape[0], 1)) * b
result = result.reshape((-1, 2))
result 
array([[ 6, 60],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 4, 40],
       [ 6, 60],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 4, 40]])
```

Yet what is more intuitive to me is to stack arrays by mean of `np.vstack` with  each column of `a` multiplied by `b` as follows:

```
result = np.vstack([c[:, None] * b for c in a.T])
result
array([[ 6, 60],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 4, 40],
       [ 6, 60],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 4, 40]])
```