# How to get the scalar multiplication between 2 matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm new with Python and programming in general.

I want to create a function that multiplies two `np.array` of the same size and get their scalar value, for example:

```
matrix_1 = np.array([[1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
matrix_2 = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1], [0, 0]])
```

I want to get `4` as output (`(1 * 1) + (1 * 2) + (0 * 1) + (1 * 1) + (1 * 0) + (0 * 0)`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Multiply two matrices element-wise
2. Sum all the elements

```
multiplied_matrix = np.multiply(matrix_1,matrix_2)

sum_of_elements = np.sum(multiplied_matrix)

print(sum_of_elements) # 4
```

Or in one shot:

```
print(np.sum(np.multiply(matrix_1, matrix_2))) # 4
```

Comment: How is this different from Willem Van Onsem answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`np.multiply()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) to multiply the two arrays *elementwise*, then we call [**`np.sum()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) on this matrix. So we thus can calculate the result with:

```
np.multiply(matrix_1, matrix_2).sum()
```

For your given sample matrix, we thus obtain:

```
>>> matrix_1 = np.array([[1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
>>> matrix_2 = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1], [0, 0]])
>>> np.multiply(matrix_1, matrix_2)
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0]])
>>> np.multiply(matrix_1, matrix_2).sum()
4
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it (Frobenius inner product) using numpy, e.g.

```
np.sum(A * B)

np.dot(A.flatten(), B.flatten())

np.trace(np.dot(A, B.T))

np.einsum('ij,ij', A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

One recommended way is using **`numpy.einsum`**, since it can be adapted to not only matrices but also multiway arrays (i.e., tensors).

- **Matrices of the same size**

Take the matrices what you give as an example,

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix_1 = np.array([[1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
>>> matrix_2 = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1], [0, 0]])
```

then, we have

```py
>>> np.einsum('ij, ij ->', matrix_1, matrix_2)
4
```

- **Vectors of the same size**

An example like this:

```py
>>> vector_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> vector_2 = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> np.einsum('i, i ->', vector_1, vector_2)
20
```

- **Tensors of the same size**

Take three-way arrays (i.e., third-order tensors) as an example,

```py
>>> tensor_1 = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[2, 3], [4, 5]], [[3, 4], [5, 6]]])
>>> print(tensor_1)
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]

 [[2 3]
  [4 5]]

 [[3 4]
  [5 6]]]
```

```py
>>> tensor_2 = np.array([[[2, 3], [4, 5]], [[3, 4], [5, 6]], [[6, 7], [8, 9]]])
>>> print(tensor_2)
[[[2 3]
  [4 5]]

 [[3 4]
  [5 6]]

 [[6 7]
  [8 9]]]
```

then, we have

```py
>>> np.einsum('ijk, ijk ->', tensor_1, tensor_2)
248
```

For more usage about **`numpy.einsum`**, I recommend:

[Understanding NumPy's einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)