# Is there a function for automatic broadcasting when multiplying two numpy arrays with different shapes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to multiply two numpy arrays with different shapes. The result should be broadcasted in such a way that e.g. the multiplication of arrays with shape (3,) and (5,) returns an array with shape (3,5). I know that this is possible using array1[:,numpy.newaxis]*array2[numpy.newaxis,:]. But what I am looking for is something more general, a function that does also automatically multiply the arrays with shapes (3,5) and (4,) to an array with shape (3,5,4). Is there any numpy function to do this? Sure, a can write myself a function but is there any function existing?

So I am looking for a function numpy.func(array1, array2) that does return an array array3 with shape (*array1.shape, *array2.shape) and values array3[i1,j1,..,i2,j2,..] = array1[i1,j1,...]*array2[i2,j2,...].

Thanks

Comment: Why not demonstrate what you want with actual input arrays and the expected output? That's orders of magnitude more-effective than just verbalising the requirements

Comment: That's broadcasting with different rules.

Comment: You can use `a[..., None] * b` which works in both cases.

Comment: See `np.einsum`. For instance, you can look at the very last example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641428/525169).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding NumPy's einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)

Comment: Yes, but not in the case np.ones((2,3,4))[...,None] * np.ones((5,6))

Comment: Try `np.einsum('ijk,lm->ijklm', np.ones((2, 3, 4)), np.ones((5, 6)))`

Comment: Yes, thanks @Praveen. I just need a further generalization so that I don't have to give np.einsum the dimensions of the arrays. Your example is perfectly fine, but I don't want to manually handle with the dimensions using ijk for dimension 3 and lm for dimension 2.

Comment: The numpy broadcasting rules add extra dimensions at the start as needed, but you have to explicitly add trailing ones.  This avoids ambiguities.  For example when adding a (3,) to a (2,), should the result be (3,2) or (2,3)?   There are programmable ways of adding trailing dimensions, but you need to define the rule clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `numpy.multiply.outer`.  [`outer`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) is a standard method that all the "ufuncs" have.

For example,

```
In [19]: a   # a has shape (3, 4)
Out[19]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [20]: b   # b has shape (5,)
Out[20]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [21]: c = np.multiply.outer(a, b)

In [22]: c.shape
Out[22]: (3, 4, 5)

In [23]: c[1, 2, 3]
Out[23]: 18

In [24]: a[1, 2]*b[3]
Out[24]: 18
```