# how do I interpret np.einsum("ijij->ij"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I am trying to make sense of np.einsum, and there does not appear to be examples related to my specific context. There are many good examples in the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), a [guide here](https://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/), [here](https://rockt.github.io/2018/04/30/einsum), and a stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum).

### However

There is no example similar to my problem which is `np.einsum("ijij->ij", padded_matrix)`

where when I output padded_matrix I get

```
     >> padded_matrix  

>> [[[[[1.         0.         0.         0.33333333 0.         0.33333333]]

   [[0.         1.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]]

   [[0.         0.         1.         0.         0.         0.        ]]

   [[0.33333333 0.         0.         1.         0.         0.33333333]]

   [[0.         0.         0.         0.         1.         0.        ]]

   [[0.33333333 0.         0.         0.33333333 0.         1.        ]]]]]
```

padded_matrix is length of 1, and is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Unfortunately copying the output for padded matrix does not work. In the actual program, padded_matrix is a call to a function too complicated to include here, hence, why I have copied its output.

The result is `[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]` but I cannot figure out how the elements were multiplied and then which axis was summed.

Given that I have not provided a working MWE, if anyone can just tell me what "ijij->ij" should do in the context of the given `padded_matrix` as a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, I would be grateful.

### My best guess is

`np.einsum("ii->i,A")` views the diagonal of Matrix A, so does this mean that in this usage, `i` is effectively replaced by `ij` due to all the padding, so that  `np.einsum("ijij->ij",padded_matrix)` is a view of the diaganol?

Comment: Nothing is multiplied since there is only one argument, `padded_matrix`.

Comment: @hpaulj I just added my guess to the bottom of the question, do you agree that it appears what is being calculated is the view of the diagonal of the interior matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no multiplication since there's only one argument:

```
In [25]: arr = np.arange(36).reshape(1,6,1,6)                                            
In [26]: arr                                                                             
Out[26]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]],

        [[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]],

        [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]],

        [[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]],

        [[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]],

        [[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]]])
In [27]: np.einsum('ijij->ij', arr)                                                      
Out[27]: array([[ 0,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35]])
```

This `einsum` is effectively a `diagonal`.

```
In [29]: np.einsum('ii->i', arr.squeeze())                                               
Out[29]: array([ 0,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35])
In [30]: np.diagonal(arr.squeeze())                                                      
Out[30]: array([ 0,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35])
```