# How do I efficiently compute the gyration tensor in numpy?

Tags: numpy, rigid-bodies

The [gyration tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyration_tensor) of a set of *N* points in 3d space is defined as

[image: Gyration tensor]

assuming the condition

[image].

How do I compute this in `numpy` without using an explicit for loop? I know that I can just do something like

```
import numpy as np

def calculate_gyration_tensor(points):
    '''
    Calculates the gyration tensor of a set of points.
    '''
    COM = centre_of_mass(points)
    gyration_tensor = np.zeros((3, 3))
    for p in points:
        gyration_tensor += np.outer(p-COM, p-COM)
    return gyration_tensor / len(points)
```

but this quickly becomes inefficient for large N, because of the for loop. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `np.einsum` like this:

```
def gyration(points):
    '''
    Calculate the gyrason tensor
    points : numpy array of shape N x 3
    '''

    center = points.mean(0)

    # normalized points
    normed_points = points - center[None,:]

    return np.einsum('im,in->mn', normed_points,normed_points)/len(points)


# test
points = np.arange(36).reshape(12,3)

gyration(points)
```

Output:

```
array([[107.25, 107.25, 107.25],
       [107.25, 107.25, 107.25],
       [107.25, 107.25, 107.25]])
```

Comment: Thanks - can you please explain what does einsum do, especially what that string means?

Comment: You can have a read on [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641428/4238408). Basically, your operation is just `normed_points.T @ normed_points`.