# Faster alternative to for loops for einstein summation?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I have a piece of code ported from Python to R. The original Python version uses np.einsum. Since I could not find an np.einsum equivalent in R, and I wanted to be sure I understood it, I directly coded it using for loops. Now, I'm wondering if there is a faster alternative.

Example code:

```
n = 2 ; d = 3 ; nx = 4 ; v = 5

array4d <- array( runif(n*nx*v*d ,-1,0),
                  dim = c(n, nx, v, d) )

array3d <- array( runif(n*v*d ,-1,0),
                  dim = c(n, v, d) )

einsum_result <- array( rep(0, n*nx*d),
                        dim = c(n, nx, d))

# original Python version: np.einsum('ikl,ijkl->ijl', array3d, array4d, optimize=False)
# R version
for (i in 1: n) {
    for( j in 1: nx) {
        for( l in 1: d ) { 
            einsum_result[i, j, l] <- einsum_result[i, j, l] +
                sum( array3d[i, , l] * array4d[i, j, , l])
        }}}
```

I have tried to remove the `j` loop  (since `j` / `nx` will usually be the biggest number) using matrix multiplication, but could not work it out correctly.
Any advise appreciated!

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question: I'm not familiar with einstein summation. But in package `calculus` there is a function `einstein`. Maybe that's what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah I found that allright but I don't think if functions the same as the Python version. Explainer on numpy.einsum here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum I'm not a huge Python fan but I do like this function! I actually find this answer clearer than the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858877/2498193 But my main question is about speed - If you see a way to make my for loops faster can forget the einsum part!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `einsum` package inspired by the NumPy function. It's `einsum` function isn't especially fast, but the `einsum_generator` function will return a cpp function (with code) that is pretty fast (once it's compiled).

```
library(einsum)

set.seed(6)

n = 5 ; d = 10; nx = 400; v = 15

array4d <- array(runif(n*nx*v*d ,-1,0),
                 dim = c(n, nx, v, d))

array3d <- array(runif(n*v*d ,-1,0),
                 dim = c(n, v, d))

einsum_result <- array(rep(0, n*nx*d),
                       dim = c(n, nx, d))

einsum1 <- function(einsum_result) {
  for (i in 1: n) {
    for( j in 1: nx) {
      for( l in 1: d ) { 
        einsum_result[i, j, l] <- einsum_result[i, j, l] +
          sum( array3d[i, , l] * array4d[i, j, , l])
      }
    }
  }
  einsum_result
}

einsum2 <- function(einsum_result) {
  for (i in 1: n) {
    for( l in 1: d ) {     
      einsum_result[i, , l] <- einsum_result[i, , l] +
        rowSums(sweep(array4d[i, , , l], MARGIN=2, array3d[i, , l], `*`) )
    }
  }
  einsum_result
}

system.time(einsumCpp <- einsum_generator("ikl, ijkl -> ijl"))
#> user  system elapsed 
#> 0.07    0.07    7.83
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(einsum1 = einsum1(einsum_result),
                               einsum2 = einsum2(einsum_result),
                               einsum = einsum("ikl, ijkl -> ijl", array3d, array4d),
                               einsumCpp = einsumCpp(array3d, array4d),
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr        min         lq      mean     median        uq        max neval
#>   einsum1  48950.100  52293.800  56474.49  55209.801  59354.95  76777.201   100
#>   einsum2   9493.801  10342.201  11381.02  11093.451  12233.45  15554.401   100
#>    einsum 168312.101 175950.002 187269.22 183263.302 192122.10 250520.301   100
#> einsumCpp    892.401   1019.101   1338.10   1356.951   1521.45   2599.701   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made some progress to eliminate the j loop using `sweep` and `rowSums`, so posting this as an answer. I've increased the dimensions of the arrays because the benefit wasn't really appreciable with the small array in the original question.

```
n = 5 ; d = 10; nx = 400; v = 15

array4d <- array( runif(n*nx*v*d ,-1,0),
                  dim = c(n, nx, v, d) )

array3d <- array( runif(n*v*d ,-1,0),
                  dim = c(n, v, d) )

einsum_result1 <- array( rep(0, n*nx*d),
                        dim = c(n, nx, d))
einsum_result2 <- einsum_result1
    
microbenchmark({
    for (i in 1: n) {
        for( j in 1: nx) {
            for( l in 1: d ) { 
                einsum_result1[i, j, l] <- einsum_result1[i, j, l] +
                    sum( array3d[i, , l] * array4d[i, j, , l])
            }}} },
    {
    for (i in 1: n) {
        #for( j in 1: nx) {
        for( l in 1: d ) {     
            einsum_result2[i, , l] <- einsum_result2[i, , l] +
                rowSums( sweep(array4d[i, , , l], MARGIN=2, array3d[i, , l], `*`) )
        }}})

     min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 40.53148 42.64406 48.30703 47.65992 50.87022 179.93073   100   b
 10.86891 11.09062 12.02787 11.22610 11.56781  27.29123   100  a 
> identical(einsum_result1, einsum_result2)
[1] TRUE
```

Anyone see a way to remove any remaining loops and replace with vectorised code? I've leave the question open for a while but if no suggestions I guess I'll accept my own answer