# converting einsum notation to for loops

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to convert the following einsum notation into for loops as I cannot fully understand what is happening to the matrices and am unable to use loops to replicate the results myself:

`np.einsum('bijc,bijd->bcd', x, x)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does x look like?

Comment: x = np.random.rand(1, 100 ,100, 24)

x.shape will provide:

(1, 100, 100, 24)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call `x_1` and `x_2` the two inputs:

```
np.einsum('bijc,bijd->bcd', x_1, x_2)
```

`bijc,bijd->bcd` boils down to `ijc,ijd->cd` since the first dimension is not used. Imagine you have `c` channels of `ixj` on one hand, and `d` channels of `ixj` on the other. The result we're looking for is a `cxb` matrix. Combining each `ixj` layer from `x_1` (there are `c` in total) to each `ixj` layer from `x_2` (there are `d` in total) makes a total of `c*d` values, this is what we're looking for. It's actually the sum of what's called the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) between the two `ixj` layers.

Since `c` is first, `c` will be in the first dim (the rows) while `d` will be the number of columns.

Here's an idea:

```
b_s, i_s, j_s, c_s = x_1.shape
d_s = x_2.shape[3]
y = np.zeros((b_s, c_s, d_s))
for b in range(b_s):
  for i in range(i_s):
    for j in range(j_s):
      for c in range(c_s):
        for d in range(d_s):
          y[b, c, d] += x_1[b, i, j, c]*x_2[b, i, j, d]
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum) might give you a better idea

Also try the following to see what happens in a simple case with `i=2`, `j=2`, `c=1` and `d=1`:

```
a = [[[1], [0]], [[0], [1]]]; b = [[[4], [1]], [[2], [2]]]
np.einsum('ijc,ijd->cd', a, b)
```

result is a `d*c` matrix of size... `1x1` (since `c` and `d` are both equal to 1). Here the result is `[6]`