# Loopless 3D Array Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

Very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3615927/419686, but different.

I have 2 matrices (A with shape (5,2,3) and B with shape (6,3,8)), and I want to perform some kind of multiplication in order to take a new matrix with shape (5,6,2,8).

Python code:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5,2,3))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(6,3,8))

C = np.zeros((5,6,2,8))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        C[i,j] = A[i].dot(B[j])
```

Is it possible to do the above operation without using a loop?

Comment: Have you tried `np.dot(A,B)`?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes. It gets (5,2,6,8). C is different if converted to 1D.

Comment: That mathstackexchange link does not have very good `numpy` answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [52]: np.random.seed(1)
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5,2,3))
    ...: B = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(6,3,8))
    ...: 
    ...: C = np.zeros((5,6,2,8))
    ...: for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(B.shape[0]):
    ...:         C[i,j] = A[i].dot(B[j])
    ...:
```

`np.dot` does `broadcast` the outer dimensions:

```
In [53]: D=np.dot(A,B)
In [54]: C.shape
Out[54]: (5, 6, 2, 8)
In [55]: D.shape
Out[55]: (5, 2, 6, 8)
```

The axes order is different, but we can easily change that:

```
In [56]: np.allclose(C, D.transpose(0,2,1,3))
Out[56]: True
In [57]: np.allclose(C, np.swapaxes(D,1,2))
Out[57]: True
```

From the `np.dot` docs:

```
dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity if there a way to do this using einsum?

Comment: The einsum expression practically writes itself from the dimensions since they are distinct.

Comment: Do you have any pointers to good resources for understanding einsum?

Comment: @DaniMesejo `np.einsum('ikl, jlm -> ijkm', A, B)`

Comment: Also, [This answer is literally cited by wikipedia for its clear description of how Einstein summation nototation works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum/33641428#33641428)

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.einsum` which is very powerful:

```
C = np.einsum('aij, bjk -> abik', A, B)
```