# Loopless 2D Array Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 matrices (A with shape (2,3) and B with shape (4,3)), and I want to perform some kind of multiplication in order to take a new matrix with shape (2,4,3).

Python code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2,3))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(4,3))
C = np.zeros((2,4,3))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        C[i,j] = A[i] * B[j]
```

Is it possible to do the above operation without using a loop?

Comment: What's wrong with your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352886/loopless-3d-array-multiplication ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loopless 3D Array Multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352886/loopless-3d-array-multiplication)

Comment: They are different, guys.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid loops?

Comment: I want GPU acceleration.

Comment: @MetallimaX, see my answer for why we try to avoid (Python level) loops in `numpy`.  With `numpy` we try to perform the loops in compiled code, where they are much faster.  That's what we commonly mean by 'vectorization', treating the array(s) as a whole thing, rather than a collection of things.

Comment: That make sense and should have been clearly exposed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you're doing a lot of high-dimensional (i.e. >2D) tensor math, you really want to:

1. get good at [Einstein Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)
2. Use `np.einsum`

Good old Albert came up with a way to deal with this for a reason, he literally wrote the book on math in high-dimensional state spaces.

In this case, your answer will be:

```
C = np.einsum('ik, jk -> ijk', A, B)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [59]: A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2,3))
    ...: B = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(4,3))
    ...: C = np.zeros((2,4,3))
    ...: for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(B.shape[0]):
    ...:         C[i,j] = A[i] * B[j]
    ...:
```

As shown in the other answer, we can do the same with `einsum`.  In contrast to your previous question, you aren't doing a `sum-of-products` on any dimension.  So all dimensions from the left carry over to the right.

```
In [60]: D = np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk',A,B)
In [61]: np.allclose(C,D)
Out[61]: True
```

But in `numpy` we can do this just as well with `broadcasting` and element-wise multiplication:

```
In [62]: E = A[:,None,:]*B[None,:,:]
In [63]: np.allclose(C,E)
Out[63]: True
```

Some comparative timings:

```
In [64]: timeit D = np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk',A,B)
7.12 µs ± 21.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [65]: timeit E = A[:,None,:]*B[None,:,:]
5.18 µs ± 76.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [66]: %%timeit
    ...: C = np.zeros((2,4,3))
    ...: for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j in range(B.shape[0]):
    ...:         C[i,j] = A[i] * B[j]
    ...: 
    ...: 

27.5 µs ± 68.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```