# Is there a better way to multiply & sum two Pytorch tensors along the first dimension?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have two Pytorch tensors, `a` & `b`, of shape `(S, M)` and `(S, M, H)` respectively. `M` is my batch dimension. I want to multiply & sum the two tensors such that the output is of shape `(M, H)`. That is, I want to compute the sum over `s` of `a[s] * b[s]`.

For example, for `S=2`, `M=2`, `H=3`:

```py
>>> import torch
>>> S, M, H = 2, 2, 3
>>> a = torch.arange(S*M).view((S,M))
tensor([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]])
>>> b = torch.arange(S*M*H).view((S,M,H))
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 3,  4,  5]],

        [[ 6,  7,  8],
         [ 9, 10, 11]]])

'''
DESIRED OUTPUT:
= [[0*[0, 1, 2] + 2*[6, 7, 8]], 
   [1*[3, 4, 5] + 3*[9, 10, 11]]]

= [[12, 14, 16],
   [30, 34, 38]]

note: shape is (2, 3) = (M, H)
'''
```

I've found one way that sort of works, using `torch.tensordot`:

```py
>>> output = torch.tensordot(a, b, ([0], [0]))
tensor([[[12, 14, 16],
         [18, 20, 22]],

        [[18, 22, 26],
         [30, 34, 38]]])
>>> output.shape
torch.Size([2, 2, 3]) # always (M, M, H)
>>> output = output[torch.arange(M), torch.arange(M), :]
tensor([[12, 14, 16],
        [30, 34, 38]])
```

But as you can see, it makes a lot of unnecessary computations and I have to slice the ones that are relevant for me.

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't involve the unnecessary computations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
(torch.unsqueeze(a, 2)*b).sum(axis=0)
>>> tensor([[12, 14, 16],
            [30, 34, 38]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use torch.einsum for that. einsum (short for Einstein summation) is a fast way to obtain a performant function for such use cases. I believe torch took that from numpy.

```
torch.einsum('sm,smh->mh', a, b)
```

Einsum contains optimizations which make it attractive from a performance point of view (at least initially). I am not sure about torch, but I believe numpy implements it in C code, and it tries to avoid creating new tensors while doing the computation. While the other answer is true, it creates an intermediate array, `torch.unsqueeze(a, 2)*b`. Creating an intermediate array is bad for RAM usage, but it is also very bad for performance. To create the intermediate array, torch first asks os to create some contiguous space in RAM, which may take some time to do. More importantly, the result of `torch.unsqueeze(a, 2)*b` will be written to that location. Then it will be taken back to the CPU back again. This back-and-forth movement of data is what hinders the speed of your program. You want to add and multiply numbers, so you have so little job for each number you fetch from memory. A modern computer can make many additions and multiplications in a single CPU clock, but cannot fetch so much bytes from memory. So it waits idle, waiting for the data to come. This is why solutions which do not create an intermediate array are more promising.

I am not sure if torch's einsum avoids creating the intermediate array. For more about einsum refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum).