# Vectorized inner product with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I need to compute many inner products for vectors stored in numpy arrays.

Namely, in mathematical terms,

V<sub>i</sub> = Σ<sub>k</sub> A<sub>i,k</sub> B<sub>i,k</sub>

and

C<sub>i,j</sub> = Σ<sub>k</sub> A<sub>i,k</sub> D<sub>i,j,k</sub>

I can of course use a loop, but I am wondering whether I could make use of a higher level operator like `dot` or `matmul` in a clever way that I haven't thought of. What is bugging me is that `np.cross` does accept arrays of vector to perform on, but `dot` and `inner` don't do what I want.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `np.einsum`

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga ! I hadn't found `einsum`, or, rather, I didn't click and read because `ein` was rather making me think of `eig`... If you make a very short answer twith this I'll accept it.

Comment: Usually people who downvote don't stay around to see comments and respond.  But my guess is that they'd like to see more detail, such as your "of course use a loop", and a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mathematical formulas already gives you the outline to define the subscripts when using [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). It is as simple as:

```
V = np.einsum('ij,ik->i', A, B)
```

which translates to `V[i] = sum(A[i][k]*B[i][k])`.

and

```
C = np.einsum('ik,ijk->ij', A, D)
```

*i.e.* `C[i][j] = sum(A[i][k]*D[i][j][k]`

You can read more about the `einsum` operator on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum).

Answer (score 1):

These can be done with element-wise multiplication and sum:

```
Vi = Σk Ai,k Bi,k
V = (A*B).sum(axis=-1)
```

and

```
Ci,j = Σk Ai,k Di,j,k
C = (A[:,None,:] * D).sum(axis=-1)
```

`einsum` may be faster, but it's a good idea of understand this approach.

To use `matmul` we have to add dimensions to fit the

```
(batch,i,j)@(batch,j,k) => (batch,k)
```

pattern.  The sum-of-products dimension is `j`.  Calculation-wise this is fast, but application here may be a bit tedious.