# Numpy matrix-vector multiplication with complex elements

Tags: python, numpy

A matrix/vector multiplication looks like that and works fine:

```
A = np.array([[1, 0],
              [0,1]])      # matrix
u = np.array([[3],[9]])    # column vector
U = np.dot(A,u)            # U = A*u
U
```

**Is there a way to keep the same structure if the elements `Xx,Xy,Yx,Yy, u,v` are 2- or 3-dimensional arrays each ?**

```
A = np.array([[Xx, Xy],
              [Yx,Yy]])
u = np.array([[u],[v]])
U = np.dot(A,u)
```

The desired result is that and works fine (so the answer to my question is rather *'nice to have'*):

```
U = Xx*u + Xy*v
V = Yx*u + Yy*v
```

## Succes Story

THX to `@loopy walt` and to `@Ivan` !

**1. it works :**
`np.einsum('ijmn,jkmn->ikmn', A, w)` and `(w.T@A.T).T` , both reproduce the correct contravariant coordinate transformation.
[image]

**2. minor issue :**
`np.einsum('ijmn,jkmn->ikmn', A, w)` and `(w.T@A.T).T` , both return an array with a pair of square brackets too much (it should be 2-dimensional). See @Ivan 's answer why:

```
array([[[   0,   50,  200],
        [ 450,  800, 1250],
        [1800, 2450, 3200]]])
```

**3. to optimize :** building the block matrix is time consuming:

```
A = np.array([[Xx, Xy],
              [Yx,Yy]])
w = np.array([[u],[v]])
```

So  the overall return time is for `np.einsum('ijmn,jkmn->ikmn', A, w)` and `(w.T@A.T).T` lager. Perhaps can this be optimized.

```
- p_einstein np.einsum('ijmn,jkmn->ikmn', A, w)        9.07 µs ± 267 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
- p_tensor: (w.T@A.T).T                                7.89 µs ± 225 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
- p_vect:   [Xx*u1 + Xy*v1, Yx*u1 + Yy*v1]             2.63 µs ± 173 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
- p_vect: including  A = np.array([[Xx, Xy],[Yx,Yy]])  7.66 µs ± 290 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Don't stop there. Create A etc.  We can help improve the code, but not start it for you.  There are too many choices that we can't make for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing `A_p` and `u_p` from @Ivan I'd like to advertise the following much simpler approach that makes use  of `__matmul__`'s inbuilt broadcasting. All we need to do is reverse the order of dimensions:

```
(u_p.T@A_p.T).T
```

This gives the same result as Ivan's `einsum` but is  a bit more flexible giving us full broadcasting without us having to figure out the corresponding format string every time.

```
np.allclose(np.einsum('ijmn,jkmn->ikmn', A_p, u_p),(u_p.T@A_p.T).T)
# True
```

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a [matrix block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) operation which you can generalize from a simple matrix operation. Your example is good because you defined your block matrices as such (I renamed them `A_p` and `u_p` to not conflict with matrix `u`):

```
A_p = np.array([[Xx, Xy],
                [Yx, Yy]])
u_p = np.array([[u], [v]])
```

If you look at a standard matrix operation, in terms of shapes you have `(r, s)` meets `(s, t)` which ultimately results in a matrix of shape `(r, t)`. The '`s`' dimension gets reduced in the process. If you're not yet familiar with the [Einstein Summation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum), and [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), you should take a quick look. Given matrices `M` and `N`, the matrix operation would look like this:

```
out = np.zeros((r, t))
for i in range(r):
   for j in range(s):
      for k in range(t):
         out[i, k] += M[i, j]*N[j, k]
```

This becomes very intuitive when you come to realize how the operation takes place: covering the entire multi-dimension space, we accumulate products on the output matrix.

With `np.einsum`, this would very similar indeed (here `M=A`, and `N=u`):

```
>>> np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, u)
array([[3],
       [9]])
```

It is useful to think with coordinates: `i`, `j`, and `k` rather than dimension sizes: `r`, `s`, and `t` respectively, just like when using `np.einsum` above. So I'll keep the former notation for the rest of the answer.

---

Now looking at the block matrices, input matrices contain blocks of matrices themselves. Matrix `M` is shape `(i, j, (m, n))` (*i.e.* `(i, j, m, n)`) where `(k, l)` refers to the shape of the blocks. Similarly, for `N` we have `(j, k, m, n)`. We've basically replaced the scalar shaped `(,)` with a 2x2 block `(m, n)`, that's all.

Therefore you can directly infer that the `A_p*u_p` operation as being:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijmn,jkmn->ikmn', A_p, u_p)
array([[[[  0,  50],
         [200, 450]]],


       [[[  0, 110],
         [440, 990]]]])
```

Which you can compare with the 'hand-made' result:

```
>>> np.stack((Xx*u + Xy*v, Yx*u + Yy*v))[:, None]
```

Notice this can be used for any `(m, n)` block and any matrix size.

You can now try implementing `A_p*u_p` with a loop just like `A*u`.

---

*Edit:* Expanding on [@loopy walt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15752941/loopy-walt)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68825058/6331369) who showed you can achieve the same result with:

```
>>> (u_p.T @ A_p.T).T
```

Indeed [`__matmul__`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) can handle multi-dimensional arrays, and will do so in the following manner (for a number of dimensions higher than 2): both inputs will be *treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes*. The inputs shapes are `(i, j, m, n)`, and `(j, k, m, n)`. In order to use `__matmul__`, we need to pull the block dimensions - namely `(m, n)` - in first positions, and leave the matrix dimensions - `(i, j)` and `(j, k)` respectively - last. The following steps need to be taken

- Transposing will have the effect of inverting the order of dimensions: `(n, m, j, i)` and `(n, m, k, j)` respectively.
- We then swap the two operands, we manage to compute something in the form of `(*, k, j) x (*, j, i) = (*, k, i)`, where `* = (n, m)`.
- Transposing the outputs leads to a shape of `(i, k, m, n)`.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: @pyano Seems like you've already accepted an answer! I'm a bit disappointed to find you basically took nothing away from the above. If you had paid just a tiny bit of attention to what's being said, you would understand how to not *return an array with a pair of square brackets too much* as you put it. I find you're interest lacking, and that you would much rather get a fast answer quickly and not worry about the details.

Comment: I am grateful to have received 2 answers. 2 possible solutions and both are valuable. For accepting an answer there is 1 possibiliy here only, but I have given an upvote to each. For an open community learning I have evaluated the 3 different approaches, indicating your merit. Sorry for disapointing you - this was not my intention.