# Memory usage of torch.einsum

Tags: python, pytorch, numpy-einsum

I have been trying to debug a certain model that uses `torch.einsum` operator in a layer which is repeated a couple of times.

While trying to analyze the GPU memory usage of the model during training, I have noticed that a certain **Einsum** operation dramatically increases the memory usage. I am dealing with multi-dimensional matrices. The operation is `torch.einsum('b q f n, b f n d -> b q f d', A, B)`.

It is also worth mentioning that:

- `x` was assigned before to a tensor of the same shape.
- In every layer (they are all identical), the GPU memory is linearly increases) after this operation, **and does not deallocate** until the end of the model iteration.

I have been wondering why this operation uses so much memory, and why the memory stays allocated after every iteration over that layer type.

Comment: The operations ends up looping over dimensions `b`, `q`, `f`, `n`, and `d` and computes `A[b][q][f][n] * B[b][f][n][d]`. Of course, depending your input dimensions, you can expect this operation to take a while to compute. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum/66007300#66007300) for more on the `einsum` operator.

Comment: I understand that this operation is computationally expensive. But why is it expensive in the **memory manner** and why after this line, the memory is not deallocated?

Comment: Well, you are still allocating `b*q*f*d` elements by the end of this operation, do you agree?

Comment: Well, it is assigned to `x`, which is already of the this shape, so I'd think it would be overwritten. wouldn't it?

Comment: Why would it? If `x` is still in the lexical scope then it will remain in memory. Can you give details on where is `x` defined exactly?

Comment: `x` is the input data sample into the NN. much like in [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html), but in `forward` there is `x = torch.einsum('b q f n, b f n d -> b q f d', A, B)`. This operation is sort of a projection layer applied on  `x`, which preserves its shape and overwrites its previous values. Am I seeing it wrong..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable "`x`" is indeed overwritten, but the tensor data is kept in memory (also called the layer's *activation*) for later usage in the backward pass.

So in turn you are effectively allocating new memory data for the result of `torch.einsum`, but you won't be replacing `x`'s memory even if it has been seemingly overwritten.

---

To pass this to the test, you can compute the forward pass under the [`torch.no_grad()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html) context manager (where those activations won't be kept in memory) and see the memory usage difference, compared with a standard inference.