# Built-in index dependent weight for tensordot in numpy?

Tags: numpy, weighted, tensordot

I would like to obtain a tensordot of two arrays with the same shape with index-dependent weight applied, without use of explicit loop. For example,

```
import numpy as np
    
A=np.array([1,2,3])
B=np.array([-2,6,9])
C=np.zeros((3,3))
for i in range(3):
     for j in range(3):
          C[i,j]=A[i]*B[j]*(np.exp(i-j)if i>j else 0)
```

Can an array similar to `C` be obtained with a built-in tool (e.g., with some options for tensordot)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized solution:

```
N = 3
C = np.tril(A[:, None] * B * np.exp(np.arange(N)[:, None] - np.arange(N)), k=-1)
```

Output:

```
>>> C
array([[ -2.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [-10.87312731,  12.        ,   0.        ],
       [-44.33433659,  48.92907291,  27.        ]])
```

Comment: I think `np.tril` with `k=-1` because of `if i>j else 0` in OPs solution.

Answer (score 0):

With [`np.einsum`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26089893/14277722) inconsistently slightly faster for some larger inputs than [broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71211392/14277722), slower for others.

```
import numpy as np
    
A=np.array([1,2,3])
B=np.array([-2,6,9])

np.einsum('ij,i,j->ij', np.tril(np.exp(np.subtract.outer(A,A)), -1), A, B)
```

Output

```
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [-10.87312731,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [-44.33433659,  48.92907291,   0.        ]])
```