# How to multiply several vectors by one matrix at once (in numpy)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2x2 rotation matrix and several vectors stored in a Nx2 array.
Is there a way to rotate them all (i.e. multiply them all by the rotation matrix) at once?

I'm sure there is a numpy method for that, it's just not obvious.

```
import numpy as np

vectors = np.array( ( (1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (4,2) )  ) # 4 2D vectors
ang = np.radians(30)
m = np.array( ( (np.cos(ang), -np.sin(ang)),
                (np.sin(ang),  np.cos(ang)) ))        # 2x2 rotation matrix

# rotate 1 vector:
m.dot(vectors[0,:])

# rotate all vectors at once??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `m` has shape `(2,2)` and `vectors` has shape `(4,2)`, you can simply do

```py
dots = vectors @ m.T
```

Then each row `i` contains the matrix-vector product `m @ vectors[i, :]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the powerful [`einsum` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641428/1862861) and do:

```py
dots = np.einsum("ij,kj->ik", vectors, m)
```