# What does np.einsum act on?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, numpy-einsum

I am facing with a problem!

How does np.einsum act on these tensors?

```
a = np.random.rand(2, 2, 5, 5)
b = np.random.rand(4, 5, 5, 1)
c = np.einsum('aijb,qwei->qweaj', b, a)
```

the output shape is: (2, 2, 5, 4, 5)

```
a = np.random.rand(2, 2, 5, 4, 5)
b = np.random.rand(1, 2, 2, 4)
c = np.einsum('fqnd,qlkjd->nlkj', b, a)
```

for this output is: (2, 5, 2, 5)

I don't know what operation(s) is performed?

Comment: [Understanding NumPy's einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum) explains 'bhwi,bhwj->bij' but about 'aijb,qwei->qweaj' or 'fqnd,qlkjd->nlkj' no!!

Comment: Your examples are combinations of the three operations of `np.einsum` that can be expressed in the signature (each explained with examples in the link). There's nothing special about them. Except for a really confusing choice of letters for the axes

Comment: This is because the axis can be swapped. Consider also reading [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

Comment: I cannot understand how they operate?
I mean how to implement my examples using some for-loops?
What do you mean they are combinations of the three ops? which ops?

Comment: The first example as a [for-loop](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QjkttfQZ5y4Rc62jFwZoQ9fL9qzDzZzV?usp=sharing). I recommend not to think in terms of for-loops when using `np.einsum`, but in the three operations multiply, sum and transpose.

Comment: `'aijb,qwei->qweaj'` - `b` only appears once, so it just does a `sum` of that array on that axis.  `i` appears on both arguments, but not the output, so it's the `dot` sum-of-products dimension.  The rest carry over to the output in the order specified.  Except for the `b` sum, this could be reduced to one `dot` (with some reshaping and transposing to make a `Xi,iY->XY` pairing).

Comment: `'fqnd,qlkjd->nlkj'` - again `f` is the sum-on-one array; the `dot` sum-of-products involves 2 dimensions, `q` and `d`.  In effect `(f) (n(qd),(qd)(lkj)->n(lkj)`, using () to group dimensions that are used together.