# how to multiply three arrays with different dimension in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJDUk.png)

L array dimension is (d,a) ,B is (a,a,N) and R is (a,d). By multiplying these arrays I have to get an array size of (d,d,N). How could I implement this is PyTorch

Answer (score 1):

A possible and straightforward approach is to apply [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html) (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)):

```
>>> torch.einsum('ij,jkn,kl->iln', L, B, R)
```

---

Where `j` and `k` are the reduced dimensions of `L` and `R` respectively. And `n` is the "batch" dimension of `B`.

- The first matrix multiplication will reduce `L@B` (let this intermediate result be `o`):

  ```
  ij,jkn->ikn
  ```
- The second matrix multiplication will reduce `o@R`:

  ```
  ikn,kl->iln
  ```

Which overall sums up to the following form:

```
ij,jkn,kl->iln
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like doing batch matrix multiplication. Like `result[:,:, i]=L@B[:,:,i]@R`. You can use:

```
B = B.permute([2,0,1])
result = torch.matmul(torch.matmul(L, B), R).permute([1,2,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`N` seems to be the batch dimension, let's forget it first.

It is simple chained matrix multiplication:

```py
d, a = 3, 5

L = torch.randn(d, a)
B = torch.randn(a, a)
R = torch.randn(a, d)

L.matmul(B).shape  # (d, a)
L.matmul(B).matmul(R).shape  # (d, d)
```

Now let's add the batch dimension `N`.
Everything is almost the same, but PyTorch works with batch dim first whereas your data is batch dim last, so a bit of `movedim` is required.

```py
N = 7
B = torch.randn(a, a, N)

L.matmul(B.movedim(-1, 0)).shape  # (N, d, a)
L.matmul(B.movedim(-1, 0)).matmul(R).shape  # (N, d, d)
L.matmul(B.movedim(-1, 0)).matmul(R).movedim(0, -1).shape  # (d, d, N)
```