# Understanding fancy einsum equation

Tags: python, torch, array-broadcasting, einops, einsum

I was reading about attention and came across this equation:

```py
import einops
from fancy_einsum import einsum
import torch

x = torch.rand((200, 10, 768))
y = torch.rand((20, 768, 64))

res = einsum("batch query_pos d_model, n_heads d_model d_head -> batch query_pos n_heads d_head", x, y)
```

And I am not able to understand the underlying operations that give the result res

I thought it might be matmul and tried this:

```py
import torch
x_ = x.unsqueeze(dim = 2).unsqueeze(dim = 2)
y_ = torch.broadcast_to(y, (1, 1, 20, 768, 64))
res2 = x_ @ y_
res2 = res2.squeeze(dim = -2)
(res == res2).all() # Prints False
```

But that does not seem to be right.

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding NumPy's einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)

Comment: Nope. I would need an explanation of underlying operations. Operations described in aforementioned post are much more simplistic than this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So whenever using `einsum` you best think about the meaning of the dimensions. Basically we perform a multiplication between the two inputs in this case. The signature passed to `einsum` shows what dimensions will be preserved and which ones will be "summed away". I simplified the signature with single letters here:

```
res = einsum("b q m, n m h -> b q n h", x, y)
```

We can read from this that both `x` and `y` have three dimensions. Furthermore both have a dimension called `m`, and this doesn't appear in the output. So we can conclude that it gets "summed away". So for each entry of the output we have following formula. For simplicity I reused the dimension names as indices, so for every `b,q,n,h` we get

```
               ___
                \
res[b,q,n,h] =  /  x[b,q,m] * y[n,m,h]
               /__
                m
```

To do this with any other function than `einsum` is usually more cumbersome. So first we need to reorder and `unsqueeze` the dimensions in a way that they are compatible to be multiplied, so we can do the following (the shapes annotated above):

```
 #(b,q,m,n,h)   (b, q, m, 1,    1)      (m, n, h)
 product     = x[:, :, :, None, None] * y.permute([1,0,2])
```

Due to the broadcasting rules, the second (`y`-) term will implicitly get the required leading dummy dimensions.
Then we can "sum away" the dimension `m`:

```
 res = product.sum(dim=2)  # (b,q,n,h)
```

So you can interpret that as a matrix multiplication if you want, or also just a scalar product, but of course with many "batch"-dimensions.