# Efficient PyTorch or NumPy broadcasting not found to avoid bottleneck operations

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, array-broadcasting

I have the following implementation in my PyTorch-based code which involves a nested for loop. The nested for loop along with the `if` condition makes the code very slow to execute. I attempted to avoid the nested loop to involve the broadcasting concepts in NumPy and PyTorch but that did not yield any result. Any help regarding avoiding the `for` loops will be appreciated.

Here are the links I have read  [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html), [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import torch

batch_size=32
mask=torch.FloatTensor(batch_size).uniform_() > 0.8

teacher_count=510
student_count=420
feature_dim=750
student_output=torch.zeros([batch_size,student_count])
teacher_output=torch.zeros([batch_size,teacher_count])

student_adjacency_mat=torch.randint(0,1,(student_count,student_count))
teacher_adjacency_mat=torch.randint(0,1,(teacher_count,teacher_count))

student_feat=torch.rand([batch_size,feature_dim])
student_graph=torch.rand([student_count,feature_dim])
teacher_feat=torch.rand([batch_size,feature_dim])
teacher_graph=torch.rand([teacher_count,feature_dim])


for m in range(batch_size):
    if mask[m]==1:
        for i in range(student_count):
            for j in range(student_count):
                student_output[m][i]=student_output[m][i]+student_adjacency_mat[i][j]*torch.dot(student_feat[m],student_graph[j])
    if mask[m]==0:
        for i in range(teacher_count):
            for j in range(teacher_count):
                teacher_output[m][i]=teacher_output[m][i]+teacher_adjacency_mat[i][j]*torch.dot(teacher_feat[m],teacher_graph[j])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Problem statement

The operation you are looking to perform is quite straightforward. If you look closely at your loop:

```
for m in range(batch_size):
  if mask[m]==1:
    for i in range(student_count):
      for j in range(student_count):
         student_output[m][i] += student_adjacency_mat[i][j]*torch.dot(student_feat[m],student_graph[j])

   if mask[m]==0:
     for i in range(teacher_count):
       for j in range(teacher_count):
         teacher_output[m][i] += teacher_adjacency_mat[i][j]*torch.dot(teacher_feat[m],teacher_graph[j])
```

Elements relevant to us:

- You have two operations separated based on a mask which can ultimately be computed separately.
- Each operation is looping through the adjacent matrices, *ie.* `student_count²`.
- The assignment operation comes down to

  ```
  output[m,i] += adj_matrix[i,j] * <feats[m] / graph[j]>
  ```

  where `adj_matrix[i,j]` is a scalar.

---

##### Using `torch.einsum`

This is a typical use case for [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html). You can read more on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum) where I also happen to have written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66007300/6331369).

If we keep away from all implementation details, the formulation with `torch.einsum` is rather self-explanatory:

```
o = torch.einsum('ij,mf,jf->mi', adj_matrix, feats, graph)
```

In pseudo-code, this comes down to:

```
o[m,i] += adj_matrix[i,j]*feats[m,f]*graph[j,f]
```

For all `i`, `j`, `m`, and `f` in your domain of interest. Which is precisely the desired operation.

Combined with the mask expanded to the appropriate form with `M = mask[:,None]`, this gives you for the student tensor:

```
>>> student = M*torch.einsum('ij,mf,jf->mi', student_adjacency_mat, student_feat, student_graph)
```

For the teacher result, you can invert the mask with `~M`:

```
>>> teacher = ~M*torch.einsum('ij,mf,jf->mi', teacher_adjacency_mat, teacher_feat, teacher_graph)
```

---

##### Using `torch.matmul`

Alternatively, since this is a rather simple application of `torch.einsum`, you can also get away with two calls to [`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html). Given `A` and `B`, two matrices indexed by `ik`, and `kj` respectively, you get `A@B` which corresponds to `ik@kj -> ij`. Therefore you can get the desired result with:

```
>>> g = student_feat@student_graph.T # mf@jf.T -> mf@fj -> mj
>>> g@student_adjacency_mat.T        # mj@ij.T -> mj@ji -> mi
```

See how the two steps relate to the torch.einsum call with 'ij,mf,jf->mi'. First `mf,jf->mj`, followed by `mj,ij->mi`.

---

Side note your current dummy student and teacher adjacenty matrices are initialized with zeros. Maybe you meant to have:

```
student_adjacency_mat=torch.randint(0,2,(student_count,student_count)).float()
teacher_adjacency_mat=torch.randint(0,2,(teacher_count,teacher_count)).float()
```