# what is an efficient way to change sign to columns of a matrix during matrix multiplications with numpy

Tags: numpy

I have two Nx3 matrices `f` and `r`, and I want to get this quantity

```
(f*r).sum()
```

Sometimes I need to change the sign of some of the columns of `r` before that calculation, for example

```
n=5
f=np.random.rand(n,3)
r=np.random.rand(n,3)

# real calculation
r[:, [0,2]]= -r[:, [0,2]]
got=(f*r).sum()
```

Is there any numpy trick to make this faster?

Edit:

maybe this?

```
got = (f * rr).sum(axis=0)
print(-got[0].sum() + got[1].sum() - got[2].sum())
```

Comment: What kind of trick do you imagine there might be?  Changing the sign of a column is no different from assigning a new value.  I suppose you could multiply by `s=np.array([[-1,0,-1]])`.  `f*r*s`.  I don't know if that's any faster.

Comment: any kind of tricks

Comment: `-r` is a multiplication`.  I don't think anyone is claiming their suggestions **are** faster.  That's for you to test on realistic size data.

Comment: I thought 1 bit is reserved for sign thus `-r` is a bit flip whereas `r*-1` is a real multiplication

Comment: I did some time testing on  (1000,3) shapes; and the differences are minor.  You'll just have to do your testing.  `-r` is faster that `-1*r`, but you are also indexing.  Look at the whole picture, not just pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `einsum` function, which allows you to perform element-wise multiplication and summation of arrays using a single function call.

```py
import numpy as np

n = 5
f = np.random.rand(n, 3)
r = np.random.rand(n, 3)

# Multiply f and r, changing the sign of columns 0 and 2 of r
result = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', f, np.array([-1, 1, -1]) * r)

print(result)
```

This should give you the same result as your original calculation, but it may be faster for large arrays. Note that the `np.array([-1, 1, -1])` term changes the sign of columns 0 and 2 of `r`.

I recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641428/17192981) for more details on how `einsum` works.

Comment: why is multiplication faster than assignment?

Comment: maybe this? `result = np.einsum("ij,ij->j", f, rr)
print(-result[0].sum() + result[1].sum() - result[2].sum())
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use *multiplier* list/array with respective multiplier for each column of `r` array:

```
(f * (r * [-1,1,-1])).sum()
```

Comment: why is multiplication faster than assignment?