# How `torch.einsum` API works?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, embedding, word-embedding

How `torch.einsum` API works?

I am trying to understand how the
`torch.einsum("ac,bc->ab",norm_max_func_embedding,norm_nl_embedding)` is calculating the similarity?

I understand this is doing manipulation of tensors.

I thikn “ac” specifies a tensor with dimensions (a,c). But what "bc->ab" is doing. Also how is it calculating the similarity. I presume similarity can be calculated by consine similarity or euclidian distance.

```
# Encode maximum function
func = "def f(a,b): if a>b: return a else return b"
tokens_ids = model.tokenize([func],max_length=512,mode="<encoder-only>")
source_ids = torch.tensor(tokens_ids).to(device)
tokens_embeddings,max_func_embedding = model(source_ids)

# Encode minimum function
func = "def f(a,b): if a<b: return a else return b"
tokens_ids = model.tokenize([func],max_length=512,mode="<encoder-only>")
source_ids = torch.tensor(tokens_ids).to(device)
tokens_embeddings,min_func_embedding = model(source_ids)

norm_max_func_embedding = torch.nn.functional.normalize(max_func_embedding, p=2, dim=1)
norm_min_func_embedding = torch.nn.functional.normalize(min_func_embedding, p=2, dim=1)
norm_nl_embedding = torch.nn.functional.normalize(nl_embedding, p=2, dim=1)

max_func_nl_similarity = torch.einsum("ac,bc->ab",norm_max_func_embedding,norm_nl_embedding)
min_func_nl_similarity = torch.einsum("ac,bc->ab",norm_min_func_embedding,norm_nl_embedding)
```

I am referring to this github repository: https://github.com/microsoft/CodeBERT/tree/master/UniXcoder

What kind of similarity is it measuring?

Any help or pointers to documentation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum

Answer (score 1):

`ac,bc->ab` refers to two input and one output tensors. The left hand side labels the dimensions of the inputs, separated by commas. The right hand side shows the dimensions of the output tensor (everything after the `->`).

- The first input tensor has dimensions `a` and `c`
- The second input tensor has dimensions `b` and `c`

Since `c` is shared by both, that dimension must be the same for both tensors. The other two dimensions are "free".

- The output tensor has dimensions `a` and `b`

Since `c` does not appear in the output, we do a sum-product along that dimension. If `c` did appear in the output, it would just be a product. For example `ab,ab->ab` is an element-wise product of two identically-shaped matrices.

Order of the dimensions matters. For example `ab->ba` is a transpose operation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @MadPhysicist is a good object-level description of what's going on, but I want to provide an intuition for what's being computed.

If you imagine that every row of the two input matrices represents a vector, then `torch.einsum("ac,bc->ab", A, B)` is computing the dot product of every vector in A with every vector in B.

In other words, in the result matrix M, the number M[i, j] represents the dot product of A[i] and B[j]. You can think of it as being similar to [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

You can also think of it as cosine similarity. If the vectors are normalized (and the code shown normalizes them in the previous step) then dot product is equivalent to cosine similarity.

Here's a code sample you can play with to build intuition about what's happening:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy
# Generate random matricies
matrix1 = np.random.rand(3,3)
matrix2 = np.random.rand(3,3)
# Normalize matrix to have length 1 in each row vector
matrix1 /= np.linalg.norm(matrix1, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
matrix2 /= np.linalg.norm(matrix2, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
print("matrix1")
print(matrix1)
print("matrix2")
print(matrix2)
# Compute dot products / cosine similarity using einsum
print("einsum")
print(np.einsum("ac,bc->ab",matrix1, matrix2))
# Note: cdist computes cosine "distance," not similarity
print("cdist")
print(1 - scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(matrix1, matrix2, metric="cosine"))
```