# Python 3D rotation of array of vectors, into same frame

Tags: python, numpy, rotation

I have a (3 column X n row) numpy array of vectors, such that each row of the array corresponds to the components of one of the n vectors in spherical coordinates. The components of each vector are in some frame (basis) that is rotated in 3D relative to the lab frame, and is not the same rotation for each vector. I also have another (3 column X n row) array that contains the spherical components of the z-axis of each of the rotated frames corresponding to each vector, in the lab frame. So, the second array tracks how we need to rotate each of the vectors in the first array. The goal is to find the components of each of the vectors, in the lab frame.

I have started to address the problem by writing a function that takes one vector in its rotated frame, and the angles of the z-axis of that rotated frame, and transforms the vector back into the lab frame. But, this involves constructing rotation matrices and I don't know how to do that without looping over each vector individually (I want to use array operations).

Is there a way to do this in Python using array operations?

Comment: `3 column X n row` arrays are not efficiently vectorized by Numpy. You should consider using a `n column X 3 row` array instead (transposed alternative). Note that you will certainly get more attention with an example showing what you want in both intput and output.

Comment: `I also have another (3 column X n row) array that contains the spherical components of the z-axis of each of the rotated frames corresponding to each vector, in the lab frame.` What does 'spherical components' mean here? Can you write a loop-based solution, so that people can try their non-loop based versions against it?

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to calculate rotation matrix for each row. To make it vectorized you need to obtain 3D tensor of size `n_rows x 3 x 3`. Can't help you with that without any code.

Next step is applying those rotation matrices to all vectors, using [einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum/33641428#33641428).

```
test_rotation_tensor = np.array([
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]],
    [[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2]],
    [[-1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, -1]],
    [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
    [[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]],
])

vector_tensor = np.array([
    [1, 2, -3],
    [1, 2, -3],
    [1, 2, -3],
    [1, 2, -3],
    [1, 2, -3],
])

result = np.einsum("ijk,ik->ij", test_rotation_tensor, vector_tensor)
```