# Understand the details of einsum application for two tensors

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, numpy-einsum

We have two tensors:

```
 a = np.arange(8.).reshape(4,2,1)
 b = np.arange(16.).reshape(2,4,2)
```

We are going to implement

```
np.einsum('ijk,jil->kl', a, b)
```

Although we could obtain its results, we were persist to understand the process details about the summation over tensors element.

Firstly we know how

```
np.einsum('jil', b)
```

changes the elements' orders of `b` tensor.

but we cannot understand how `np.einsum('ijk,jil->kl', a, b)` combine (sums) tensors elements.

For tracking the process we used strings:

```
aa=[[['e'],
  ['r']],

 [['t'],
  ['y']],

 [['u'],
  ['o']],

 [['p'],
  ['q']]]
```

and

```
bb=[[[ 'x', 'c'],
  [ 'v' , 'n'],
  [ 'm',  'h'],
  [ 'f' , 'd']],

 [[ 's',  'w'],
  [ 'a','z'],
  ['j', 'k'],
  ['l', 'b']]]
```

Because we wanted to see how different elements combine for obtaining `np.einsum('ijk,jil->kl', aa, bb)`!

However `np.einsum('jil', bb)` works correctly but it did not show me the details of summation over elements.

Comment: whats there not to understand? compute `np.einsum('ijk,jil->ijkl', a, b)` and you will see how the multiplication is done. Then you sum over axes 0 and 1

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to understand this.

One is to use the example @Onyambu suggests.

```py
>>> np.einsum('ijk,jil->ijkl', a, b)

array([[[[  0.,   0.]],
        [[  8.,   9.]]],

       [[[  4.,   6.]],
        [[ 30.,  33.]]],

       [[[ 16.,  20.]],
        [[ 60.,  65.]]],

       [[[ 36.,  42.]],
        [[ 98., 105.]]]])
```

By including i and j as indexes on the output, the output array no longer has shape (k, l), but (i, j, k, l). Also, none of the multiplied elements are being summed together. Each element of the output array is the product of one element from each of the original arrays.

To get back to the original behavior, we can sum by axis 1:

```py
>>> np.einsum('ijk,jil->ijkl', a, b).sum(axis=1)
array([[[  8.,   9.]],
       [[ 34.,  39.]],
       [[ 76.,  85.]],
       [[134., 147.]]])
```

Then sum by axis 0:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijk,jil->ijkl', a, b).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=0)

array([[252., 280.]])
```

Another way to understand this is to convert it to an explicit loop.

The following code is equivalent to this einsum, but slower. (It also does not check that the shapes of A and B are compatible.)

```
def sum_array(A, B):
    i_len, j_len, k_len = A.shape
    _, _, l_len = B.shape
    
    ret = np.zeros((k_len, l_len))
    for i in range(i_len):
        for j in range(j_len):
            for k in range(k_len):
                for l in range(l_len):
                    ret[k, l] += A[i, j, k] * B[j, i, l]
    return ret
```

This gives us the same result, `array([[252., 280.]])`.

Notice how the inner line of the loop, `ret[k, l] += A[i, j, k] * B[j, i, l]` is similar to the einsum subscript `'ijk,jil->kl'`, except that the `kl` has been moved to the beginning, and `ijk` is being used to index A, and `jil` is being used to index B.

#### More information

[Understanding NumPy's einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)

Comment: without eisum `(a.transpose(1,0,2) * b).sum((0,1))`

Comment: @Onyambu I don't think that's equivalent. Consider the counter-example `a = np.arange(16.).reshape(4,2,2); b = np.arange(16.).reshape(2,4,2)` This does not provide the same result as einsum. Might work with some newaxis sprinkled in, though. :)

Comment: SSure. Just for the specific example. Of course one has to know how to move the axes around and how to reshape before the multiplication