# Clarification on einsum equation

Tags: numpy, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, tensor, numpy-einsum

I came across some code on Huggingface (in a self-attention module) that uses `torch.einsum`, which I'm not too familiar with and would like some help interpreting. I've looked through [this list of basic operations and their implementations in NumPy/PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894693/understanding-pytorch-einsum). The inputs are a 4D tensor and a 3D tensor.

This is the (explicit) einsum string:

```
'bhld,lrd->bhlr'
```

(Another einsum string used is similar:

```
'bhrd,lrd->bhlr')
```

What does this mean/how else could this be implemented without using einsum? E.g., the second tensor must be transposed so that d is the first dimension.

Comment: checkout [numpy einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).  You can also read [on wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77677498/understand-the-details-of-einsum-application-for-two-tensors/) for a worked example of picking apart an einsum call.

Answer (score 1):

```
'bhld,lrd->bhlr'
```

First arg is 4d, 2nd is 3d, result is 4d

'bh' passes thru unchanged. 'r' also. 'ld' dimensions are matched, with multiplication, and sum of products on
'd'.

It terms of a broadcasted sum of products I think the equivalent is (not tested)

```
(A[:,:,:,None,:] * B[None, None, :,:,:]).sum(axis=-1)
```

With matmul, put 'd' of `B` 2nd to the last.  Ensure that the first 3 dimensions broadcast.

```
A[:,:,:,None,:] @ B.transpose(0,2,1)[None, None, :,:,:]
```

Same sum on 'd', 'r' is shared among all 3

```
'bhrd,lrd->bhlr'
```