# How to matrix multiply each column from two matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices,

```
A = np.array([[1, 3, 5],
             [2, 4, 6]])
b = np.array([[7, 9, 11],
             [8, 10, 12]])
```

The operation I want to perform is multiplying

```
# Column 1
A_1 = np.matmul([[1],[2]], [[7, 8]])
# [1]
# [2] * [7, 8] = [7, 8]
#                 [14, 16]

# Column 2
A_2 = np.matmul([[3],[4]], [[9, 10]])
# [3]
# [4] * [9, 10] = [27, 30]
#                 [36, 40]

# A_1+A_2 = [34 38
#           50 56]


....
# Column N
```

For each column then sum up the resulting matrices. My matrices will always have a shape of (2, N). In words, multiply i'th column of matrix A with the transpose of the i'th column of matrix B then sum up each 2x2 matrix from each column pair.

I know I can probably loop over each entry and calculate it this way but I don't think thats the spirit of numpy and think there has to be a better way.

Comment: Show the loop solution.  It will be clearer than your words.  Correctness is better than this 'spirit of numpy' - whatever that is?

Comment: You really don't understand what that means? Let me explain it to you then. Part of the purpose of numpy is for efficient and parallel array computation. Performing this calculation in a loop would neglect any parallelization or optimization numpy provides. @hpaulj

Comment: That was a tongue in cheek comment about the 'spirit of numpy'.  I've answered enough numpy vectorization questions to qualify as your 'egg sucking grandmother' :)  But for many of those I've first sought a [mcve], even if it doesn't qualify as the fastest and prettiest of `numpy` code.

Answer (score 2):

Well isn't this just `A @ b.T`?

Comment: Is this correct? The given example of the two columns multiplies together to form a 2x2 matrix, which then sums to 45, which does not appear anywhere in the output of this calculation.

Comment: Yea this answer is incorrect. It would be correct on a column level but I need it done for each column in a large matrix.

Comment: Without the expected result who can tell what is correct or incorrect? This matches your wordy description " In words, multiply i'th column of matrix A with the transpose of the i'th column of matrix B then sum up each 2x2 matrix from each column pair." if not explain better and provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

```
In [62]: A = np.array([[1, 3, 5],
    ...:              [2, 4, 6]])
    ...: b = np.array([[7, 9, 11],
    ...:              [8, 10, 12]])
```

The suggested answers, with some confusion:

```
In [63]: A@b.T
Out[63]: 
array([[ 89,  98],
       [116, 128]])

In [64]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ik',A,b)
Out[64]: 
array([[ 89,  98],
       [116, 128]])

In [65]: np.einsum('ij,kj->j',A,b)
Out[65]: array([ 45, 133, 253])
```

Your partial calculation:

```
In [70]: [A[:,[i]]*b[:,[i]].T for i in range(3)]
Out[70]: 
[array([[ 7,  8],
        [14, 16]]),
 array([[27, 30],
        [36, 40]]),
 array([[55, 60],
        [66, 72]])]
```

summing 2 of those:

```
In [72]: sum([A[:,[i]]*b[:,[i]].T for i in range(2)])
Out[72]: 
array([[34, 38],
       [50, 56]])
```

Summing all 3:

```
In [73]: sum([A[:,[i]]*b[:,[i]].T for i in range(3)])
Out[73]: 
array([[ 89,  98],
       [116, 128]])
```

But wait, where have I seen those numbers before?

Since these are both 2d arrays, we can use the old-school `np.dot`

```
In [74]: np.dot(A,b.T)
Out[74]: 
array([[ 89,  98],
       [116, 128]])
```

Hopefully this shows why a clear, worked out example, even if written in loops is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do this with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy-einsum):

```py
A = np.array([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]])
B = np.array([[7, 9, 11], [8, 10, 12]])

out = np.einsum("ij,kj->ik", A, B)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[ 89  98]
 [116 128]]
```

---

EDIT: As @NickODell stated, if you want to sum the 2x2 matrices to one number on each column you can use:

```py
out = np.einsum("ij,kj->j", A, B)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[ 45 133 253]
```

Comment: in other simpler words: `A @ b.T`

Comment: I interpret the question to be asking for the outer product of each column vector, rather than the inner product. I think `np.einsum('ij,kj->j', A, B)` lines up better with what the OP has described about the output of this algorithm.

Comment: @NickODell Reading the question again you might be right... I update the answer and add this option.

Comment: This works! Thank you. Can you briefly describe the "ij,kj->ik" part, I read the einsum documentation but am having trouble understanding how this works.

Comment: @Lorde213423432e43434 Look at the first answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum There are nice pictures what's happening with the einsum formula.

Comment: Thanks. I have also edited my question to make it more clear about the sum

Comment: @Julien, his partial calculation suggests he does want your product.