# Multilinear maps in python using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

In python I have a three dimensional array `T` with size `(n,n,n)`, and a 2-D array, with size `(n,k)`.

In linear algebra, the multilinear map defined by `T` and applied to `W`, in code would be:

```
X3 = np.zeros((k,k,k))
    for i in xrange(k):
       for j in xrange(k):
            for t in xrange(k):
               for l in xrange(n):
                 for m in xrange(n)
                    for h in xrange(n):
                        X3[i, j, t] += M3[l, m, h] * W[l, i] * W[m, j] * W[h, t]
```

See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map

For a reference.

This is very slow. I am wondering if there exist any alternative or any pre build function in numpy that can speed up the operations.

Comment: What are your typical `n` and `k`?

Comment: n can be big (up to 100000) k up to 1000, more or less..

Comment: So, you would have an array `M3` of shape `(100000,100000,100000)` as the input? Isn't that too big to fit into RAM?

Comment: @UlderiqueDemoitre If any of answers below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Einstein summation convention? Use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)!

```
X3 = np.einsum('lmh,li,mj,ht->ijt', M3, W, W, W)
```

EDIT:

Out of curiosity, I just ran some benchmarks comparing `np.einsum` to Divakar's approach. The difference is hugely against `np.einsum`!

```
import numpy as np

def approach1(a, b):
    x = np.einsum('lmh,li,mj,ht->ijt', a, b, b, b)

def approach2(a, b):
    p1 = np.tensordot(b, a, axes=(0,0))
    p2 = np.tensordot(p1, b, axes=(1,0))
    x = np.tensordot(p2, b, axes=(1,0))

n = 100
k = 10
a = np.random.random((n, n, n))
b = np.random.random((n, k))
%timeit approach1(a, b)      # => 1 loop, best of 3: 26 s per loop
%timeit approach2(a, b)      # => 100 loops, best of 3: 4.23 ms per loop
```

There's some discussion about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149201/why-is-numpys-einsum-slower-than-numpys-built-in-functions). It all seems to come down to the generality that `np.einsum` tries to achieve — at the cost of being able to offload computations to low-level linear algebra packages.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit to my post to avoid the swapaxes, both for performance and being concise. Could you please update the timings test? I am not expecting huge changes, but mostly to relate to the appropriate post. Thanks!

Comment: @Divakar: Done! There's a difference of a factor of 10 with your previous code.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using a series of dot-products -

```
# Get partial products and thus reach to final output
p1 = np.tensordot(W,M3,axes=(0,0))
p2 = np.tensordot(p1,W,axes=(1,0))
X3out = np.tensordot(p2,W,axes=(1,0))
```