# Multiplying N matrices - symbolic calculation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy, lambdify

What is the most efficient (quickest) way to multiply 20 identical 6x6 matrices (M)?

```
N = 20
w = sy.Symbol("w");v = sy.Symbol("v");p = sy.Symbol("p");q = sy.Symbol("q");c = 1;n = 1;nc = 1
M = np.array([[w*p*q,w*q,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,v,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,nc,0,c], 
              [0,0,0,0,v,0], 
              [w,w,v,nc,0,c],
              [0,0,0,n,0,1]])
Mi = np.array([[w*p*q,w*q,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,v,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,nc,0,c],
               [0,0,0,0,v,0], 
               [w,w,v,nc,0,c],
               [0,0,0,n,0,1]])
for l in range(N-1):
    M = np.dot(M, Mi)
difZ = sy.diff(Z2,w)
expr = w*(np.divide(difZ,Z2))
Z_lamda = sy.lambdify([w,v,p,q], expr, "numpy")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838352/multiply-several-matrices-in-numpy

Comment: The last 3 lines of your code sample are useless - you haven't defined `Z2`.  Your array, `M` is object dtype, containing `sympy` objects.  Math using object dtype arrays is much slower than math using `numpy` numeric arrays, and somewhat hit-or-miss, depending on whether it can delegate the actions to methods of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your special use case, I'd recommend using [`numpy.linalg.matrix_power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html#numpy-linalg-matrix-power) (which wasn't mentioned in the linked question).

## Timings

Here's the setup code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing(pretty_print=False)

N = 20
w = sy.Symbol("w");v = sy.Symbol("v");p = sy.Symbol("p");q = sy.Symbol("q");c = 1;n = 1;nc = 1
M = np.array([[w*p*q,w*q,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,v,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,nc,0,c], 
              [0,0,0,0,v,0], 
              [w,w,v,nc,0,c],
              [0,0,0,n,0,1]])
Mi = M.copy()
```

and here's some timings comparing your original iterative `dot` approach to `matrix_power`:

```
%%timeit
M = Mi.copy()
for _ in range(N-1):
    M = np.dot(M, Mi)
# 527 ms ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
np.linalg.matrix_power(Mi, N)
# 6.63 ms ± 96.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So `matrix_power` is about 80X faster.

## Added bonus: `matrix_power` works better with arrays of Sympy expressions

For whatever reason, `matrix_power` seems to work better with Sympy than the iterative `dot` method. The expressions in the resulting array will be more simplified with fewer terms. Here's how you can count the terms in the result array:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy

def countterms(arr):
    return np.sum([len(e.args) for e in arr.flat])

N = 20
w = sy.Symbol("w");v = sy.Symbol("v");p = sy.Symbol("p");q = sy.Symbol("q");c = 1;n = 1;nc = 1
M = np.array([[w*p*q,w*q,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,v,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,nc,0,c], 
              [0,0,0,0,v,0], 
              [w,w,v,nc,0,c],
              [0,0,0,n,0,1]])
Mi = M.copy()

for _ in range(N-1):
    M = np.dot(M, Mi)

Mpow = np.linalg.matrix_power(Mi, N)

print("%d terms total in looped dot result\n" % countterms(M))
print("%d terms total in matrix_power result\n" % countterms(Mpow))
```

Output:

```
650 terms total in looped dot result

216 terms total in matrix_power result
```

In particular, `print(Mpow)` runs much, much faster than `print(M)`.

Comment: `M` is an object dtype array.  `np.dot` works because the elements themselves implement basic math, * and +.  It is not using the fast numeric BLAS routines.  `matrix_power` gains speed by doing repeated matrix squares, reducing the total number of calls to `np.dot`.

Comment: `matrix_power` is written in Python, using `np.dot` (or `matmul` in non-object cases).  No special `C` code.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the info. I updated my answer to match, and included some timings. `matrix_power` is a heck of a lot faster, even without any C deep magic. "repeated matrix squares, reducing the total number of calls to `np.dot`": is that something like the [peasant multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication)?

Comment: `matrix_power(M,4)` produces the same thing as `temp=np.dot(M,M); M4=np.dot(temp,temp)`.  `matrix_power(M,5)` would be the `M4` dotted once more with `M`.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, tremendous difference!